# How can I get a flat result from a list comprehension instead of a nested list?

Tags: functional-programming, python, list-comprehension

I have a list `A`, and a function `f` which takes an item of `A` and returns a list. I can use a list comprehension to convert everything in `A` like `[f(a) for a in A]`, but this returns a list of lists. Suppose my input is `[a1,a2,a3]`, resulting in `[[b11,b12],[b21,b22],[b31,b32]]`.

How can I get the *flattened* list `[b11,b12,b21,b22,b31,b32]` instead? In other words, in Python, how can I get what is traditionally called `flatmap` in functional programming languages, or `SelectMany` in .NET?

(In the actual code, `A` is a list of directories, and `f` is `os.listdir`. I want to build a flat list of subdirectories.)

---

<sub>See also: [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914) for the more general problem of flattening a list of lists after it's been created.</sub>

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can have nested iterations in a single list comprehension:

```py
[filename for path in dirs for filename in os.listdir(path)]
```

which is equivalent (at least functionally) to:

```py
filenames = []
for path in dirs:
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        filenames.append(filename)
```

Comment: Although clever, that is hard to understand and not very readable.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question as asked. This is rather a workaround for not encountering the problem in the first place. What if you already have a list of lists. For example, what if your list of lists is a result of the multiprocessing module's map function? Perhaps the itertools solution or the reduce solution is best.

Comment: Dave31415: `[ item for list in listoflists for item in list ]`

Comment: 'readability' is a subjective judgment.  I find this solution quite readable.

Comment: Can you please explain your code a bit? Which `for` execute first and as @rampion pointed how do we get listoflists in the middle.

Comment: I thought it was readable too, until I saw the order of the terms... :(

Comment: @cz Same order as if you write nested loops with list.append instead of a comprehension. See [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(langage)#Programmation_fonctionnelle) (french wikipedia, but the relevant part is the Python example).

Comment: This is completely useless in any real use case. Python is really lacking this functionality. How would I for example get every `href` attribute of ever `a` tag in a list of `BeautifulSoup` objects?

Comment: @Philippe [a.href for soup in soups for a in soup]

Comment: I'm no expert here, but it seems like Python vs LINQ would be`c for a in source for b in a for c in b` vs `from a in source from b in a from c in b select c`, so it's really just taking the "select c" at the end and moving it to the beginning, removing the word "select". I hate it, but it is what it is.

Comment: Just adding a simple running example that helped me:

`[x for y in ((1,2,3), (4,5,6)) for x in y]`

Comment: This directly answers the question by creating a flat list directly from the comprehension, rather than flattening a list of lists after the fact. Other answers here really belong on the bigger canonical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914 instead.

Comment: @Dave31415 on the contrary; this is one of the few questions that actually answers the question as asked; "not encountering the problem in the first place" **is the question**. "flat map" operations in other languages accept a predicate and directly create a flat list of results, rather than flattening a list of lists after the fact. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026523/523612; the Python equivalent syntax for `\x -> [x,x]` is `lambda x: [x,x])`.

Answer (score 96):

```
>>> from functools import reduce  # not needed on Python 2
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6]]
>>> reduce(list.__add__, list_of_lists)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[The `itertools` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077074) is more efficient, but this feels very pythonic.

Comment: For a list of 1,000 sublists, this is [100 times slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists/45323085#45323085) that the `itertools` way and the difference only gets worse as your list grows.

Answer (score 73):

You can find a good answer in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
import itertools

def flatten(list_of_lists):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
```

Comment: The same approach can be used to define flatmap, as proposed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037408/1048186) and this [external blog post](http://naiquevin.github.io/a-look-at-some-of-pythons-useful-itertools.html)

Answer (score 39):

The question proposed `flatmap`. Some implementations are proposed but they may unnecessary creating intermediate lists. Here is one implementation that's based on iterators.

```
def flatmap(func, *iterable):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(func, *iterable))

In [148]: list(flatmap(os.listdir, ['c:/mfg','c:/Intel']))
Out[148]: ['SPEC.pdf', 'W7ADD64EN006.cdr', 'W7ADD64EN006.pdf', 'ExtremeGraphics', 'Logs']
```

In Python 2.x, use `itertools.map` in place of `map`.

Answer (score 24):

You could just do the straightforward:

```
subs = []
for d in dirs:
    subs.extend(os.listdir(d))
```

Comment: Yep, this is fine (though not quite as good as @Ants') so I'm giving it a +1 to honor its simplicity!

Answer (score 16):

You can concatenate lists using the normal addition operator:

```
>>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The built-in function `sum` will add the numbers in a sequence and can optionally start from a specific value:

```
>>> sum(xrange(10), 100)
145
```

Combine the above to flatten a list of lists:

```
>>> sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can now define your `flatmap`:

```
>>> def flatmap(f, seq):
...   return sum([f(s) for s in seq], [])
... 
>>> flatmap(range, [1,2,3])
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

**Edit:** I just saw the critique in the comments for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists/1077067#1077067) and I guess it is correct that Python will needlessly build and garbage collect lots of smaller lists with this solution. So the best thing that can be said about it is that it is very simple and concise if you're used to functional programming :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
subs = []
map(subs.extend, (os.listdir(d) for d in dirs))
```

(but Ants's answer is better; +1 for him)

Comment: Using reduce (or sum, which saves you many characters and an import;-) for this is just wrong -- you keep uselessly tossing away old lists to make a new one for each d. @Ants has the right answer (smart of @Steve to accept it!).

Comment: You can't say in general that this is a bad solution. It depends on whether performance is even an issue. Simple is better unless there is a reason to optimize. That's why the reduce method could be best for many problems.  For example you have a slow function that produces a list of a few hundred objects. You want to speed it up by using multiprocessing 'map' function. So you create 4 processes and use reduce to flat map them. In this case the reduce function is fine and very readable. That said, it's good that you point out why this can be suboptimal. But it is not always suboptimal.

Answer (score 10):

```
import itertools
x=[['b11','b12'],['b21','b22'],['b31']]
y=list(itertools.chain(*x))
print y
```

itertools will work from python2.3 and greater

Answer (score 5):

You could try `itertools.chain()`, like this:

```
import itertools
import os
dirs = ["c:\\usr", "c:\\temp"]
subs = list(itertools.chain(*[os.listdir(d) for d in dirs]))
print subs
```

`itertools.chain()` returns an iterator, hence the passing to `list()`.

Answer (score 4):

**This is the most simple way to do it:**

```
def flatMap(array):
  return reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, array)
```

The 'a+b' refers to concatenation of two lists

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyxtension](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxtension/1.0):

```py
from pyxtension.streams import stream
stream([ [1,2,3], [4,5], [], [6] ]).flatMap() == range(7)
```

Comment: Can this directly replace a list comprehension like `[f(a) for a in A]` (where `f` returns a list)? Or does it only flatten a list of lists after the fact?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel -it actually do both: it can replace the list comprehension with applying a function `f` in this way: `stream([ [1,2,3], [4,5], [], [6] ]).flatMap( f )`
AND it returns a flatten list after that, with `f` applied over the elements of the flattened list

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is specifically about replacing a list comprehension, since otherwise it would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914. Mind editing to show a more appropriate example?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, you are right - I indeed missed the spec that `f` returns a list. Can't edit the answer, so will post a new answer here:
No - it can't directly replace that list comprehension, as `[f(a) for a in A]` (where `f` returns a list)? is simply a mapping, which would be equivalent to `stream(A).map( f )`,
while `stream(A).flatMap( f )`  would be equivalent of `stream(A).map( f ).flatMap()` - I hope this is slightly more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Google brought me next solution:

```
def flatten(l):
   if isinstance(l,list):
      return sum(map(flatten,l))
   else:
      return l
```

Comment: Would be a little better if it handled generator expressions too, and would be a lot better if you explained how to use it...

Comment: This answer belongs on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/ instead, but it would likely be a duplicate there.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for `flatmap` and found this question first. `flatmap` is basically a generalization of what the original question asks for. If you are looking for a concise way of defining `flatmap` for summable collections such as lists you can use

```py
sum(map(f,xs),[])
```

It's only a little longer than just writing

```
flatmap(f,xs)
```

but also potentially less clear at first.

The sanest solution would be to have `flatmap` as a basic function inside the programming language but as long as it is not, you can still define it using a better or more concrete name:

```py
# `function` must turn the element type of `xs` into a summable type.
# `function` must be defined for arguments constructed without parameters.
def aggregate(function, xs):
    return sum( map(function, xs), type(function( type(xs)() ))() )

# or only for lists
aggregate_list = lambda f,xs: sum(map(f,xs),[])
```

Strings are not summable unfortunately, it won't work for them.
You can do

```py
assert( aggregate_list( lambda x: x * [x], [2,3,4] ) == [2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] )
```

but you **can't** do

```
def get_index_in_alphabet(character):
    return (ord(character) & ~0x20) - ord('A')

assert(aggregate( lambda x: get_index_in_alphabet(x) * x, "abcd") == "bccddd")
```

For strings, you need to use

```py
aggregate_string = lambda f,s: "".join(map(f,s))  # looks almost like sum(map(f,s),"")

assert( aggregate_string( lambda x: get_index_in_alphabet(x) * x, "abcd" ) == "bccddd" )
```

It's obviously a mess, requiring different function names and even syntax for different types. Hopefully, Python's type system will be improved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `flatten` function using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = [[i+k for i in range(10)] for k in range(10)]
matrix_flat = np.array(arr).flatten()
```

[numpy documentation `flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not `flatten` and `flat_map` functions appliable to any iterable using generators?

```py
def flatten(iters):
    for it in iters:
        for elem in it:
            yield elem

def flat_map(fn, it):
    return flatten(map(fn, it))
```

Usage is very simple:

```py
for e in flat_map(range, [1, 2, 3]):
    print(e, end=" ")
# Output: 0 0 1 0 1 2
```

As an interesting trivia, you can write `flatten` in a recursive manner aswell. Analysis left to the interested reader!

```py
def flatten(it):
    try:
        yield from next(it)
        yield from flatten(it)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can effectively flatten any nested list structure. Below is an example code snippet:

```
lst = [1,2,4, [3,2,5,6], [1,5,6,[9,20,23,45]]]

def flatten_list(l):
  flat_data = []
  for i in l:
    if type(i) != list:    # or you can use:  if isinstance(i, list):
      flat_data.append(i)
    else:
      flat_data.extend(flatten_list(i))
  return flat_data

print(flatten_list(lst))
```

In this code, the `flatten_list` function recursively traverses the nested list, appending non-list elements to the `flat_data` list. When encountering nested lists, it calls itself recursively until all elements are flattened. This approach ensures that any level of nesting within the list is handled effectively, resulting in a single flattened list as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can effectively flatten any nested list structure. Below is an example code snippet:

```
lst = [1,2,4, [3,2,5,6], [1,5,6,[9,20,23,45]]]

def flatten_list(l):
  flat_data = []
  for i in l:
    if type(i) != list:    # or you can use:  if isinstance(i, list):
      flat_data.append(i)
    else:
      flat_data.extend(flatten_list(i))
  return flat_data

print(flatten_list(lst))
```

In this code, the `flatten_list` function recursively traverses the nested list, appending non-list elements to the `flat_data` list. When encountering nested lists, it calls itself recursively until all elements are flattened.

Answer (score -2):

```
If listA=[list1,list2,list3]
flattened_list=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,listA)
```

This will do.

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution if the sublists are large. The `+` operator between two lists is O(n+m)