# An ALGORITHM to create one list from "X" nested lists in Python

Tags: python

What is the simplest way to create this list in Python?

First, suppose I have this nested list:

```
oldList = [ [{'letter':'a'}], [{'letter':'b'}], [{'letter':'c'}] ]
```

I want a function to spit out:

```
newList = [ {'letter':a}, {'letter':'b'}, {'letter':'c'} ]
```

Well, this could be done manually. However, what if there are **three nested**? ...**X nested**

Tricky? :)

Comment: Not tricky.  Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python, which is itself a duplicate of other questions.

Comment: Duplicate of this, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.daniel-lemire.com/blog/archives/2006/05/10/flattening-lists-in-python/

from that link (with a couple minor changes:

```
def flatten(l):
  if isinstance(l, list):
     return sum(map(flatten,l),[])
  else:
     return [l]
```

Comment: Way too broad: a dict also has an `__iter__`, for example, yet the OP's example makes it totally clear that he does NOT want to "flatten" dicts, only lists!

Comment: :) good point. that was an unnecessary edit by me from the original. (the other edit being the second parameter on sum)

Comment: A side note: PEP 8 encourages not to use lowercase L as an identifier.  This makes the code less legible, because `l` (L) looks like `1` (one).

Answer (score 4):

Recursive solutions are simplest, but limited to at most a few thousand levels of nesting before you get an exception about too-deep recursion. For real generality, you can eliminate recursion by keeping your own stack; iterators are good things to keep on said stack, and the whole function's best written as a generator (just call `list(flatten(thelist))` if you really want a huge list result).

```
def flatten(alist):
  stack = [iter(alist)]
  while stack:
    current = stack.pop()
    for item in current:
      if isinstance(item, list):
        stack.append(current)
        stack.append(iter(item))
        break
      yield item
```

Now *this* should let you handle as many levels of nesting as you have virtual memory for;-).

Comment: you can also increase the recursion limit with sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: @Alex: glad to see you here.  Sorry for a bit of meta, here, is my response re. copyrights etc?  (BTW great  non-recursive sol')

Comment: @gnibbler, only up to a limit, NOT without bounds. @mjv, by posting a link to a google books snippet you're most certainly in the clear (not sure how O'Reilly feels about republication in other public fora such as this one).

Comment: @Alex M Thanks for the hint.  Hopefully the publisher would see it as free advertisement.  'nough on this, back to coding...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is this

**Only you can prevent nested lists**

Do not create a list of lists using `append`.  Create a flat list using `extend`.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Python Cookbook**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007973) Martelli, Ravenscroft and Asher 2005 O'Reilley also offers a solution to this flattening problem.
See *4.6 Flattening a nested sequence.*
This solution uses generators which can be a good thing if the lists are long.
Also, this solution deals equaly well with lists or tuples.

Note: Oops... I rushed a bit. I'm unsure of the legality of reproducing this snippet here...
let me look for policy / precedents in this area.

**Edit:** later found reference as a Google Books preview.

Here's a link to this section of the book in [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q0s6Vgb98CQC&pg=PA157&dq=%22flattening+a+Nested+Sequence%22+%2Bproblem&lr=#v=onepage&q=%22flattening%20a%20Nested%20Sequence%22%20%2Bproblem&f=false)

Comment: As a co-author of that recipe (yep, Luther Blissett, c'est moi!-), I know think the last, most advanced, recursion-removal recipe is a tad too fancy -- the version I wrote (from scratch, no copying) in my answer above is slightly less optimized (does a bit more pop/append pairs than strictly needed... but they're cheap operations!), but, IMHO, easier to follow (no `else` branches, while the printed version has two;-).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Alex Martelli's post as usual. Just want to add a not recommended trick:

```
from Tkinter import _flatten
print _flatten(oldList)
```