# Lower keys of nested dictionary and merge data if the lower key already exists

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have a tree structure, builded from a nested dictionary :

```
{
  'test': {
    'Data': {},
  },
  'Test': {
    'data': {
      'Other': {},
    },
  },
}
```

And I want transform it to :

```
{
  'test': {
    'data': {
      'other': {},
    },
  },
}
```

Is there any way to perform this transformation in python ?

I insist : all value are dictionary.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: With merging the dicts if the lower key already exist

Comment: See [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5946236/2009616)... you'll just need to add some lowercasing code.

Comment: Have tried doing a lower on the json and then converting it o a dictionary? I'm not sure if this'd work; I'm on my phone but otherwise I'd try it myself.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to merge dictionaries and lower-case the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a recursive function call to lowercase the keys:

```
>>> def lower_keys(tree):
        if not tree:
            return tree
        return {k.lower() : lower_keys(v) for k, v in tree.items()}

>>> t = {
  'test': {
    'Data': {},
  },
  'Test': {
    'data': {
      'Other': {},
    },
  },
}

>>> lower_keys(t)
{'test': {'data': {'other': {}}}}
```