# How can I merge dictionary values by key?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, collections, tuples

**Before claiming this question is a duplicate**

I found a [similar question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key). I think it's because I'm using python3, but I received `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'` and `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'` for various solutions proposed.

**Question**

I have two dictionaries with identical keys. I would like to merge them into a single dictionary in which the keys remain the same but the values are combined.

As an example, I have some sample gradebook data. I would like to place the dictionary key-value pairs as labels in a legend.

```
dict_one = {'average' : 84, 'median' : 86.5, 'stdev' : 3.35}
dict_two = {'average' : 'B', 'median' : 'B+', 'stdev' : 'F'}
```

How can I modify the dictionaries to get back

```
dict_res = {'average' : (84, 'B'), 'median' : (86.5, 'B+'), 'stdev' : (3.35, 'F')}
```

I think a tuple (example: `(84, 'B')`) would be best, but a list (example: `[84, 'B']`) can work too.

Comment: `{key:(dict_one[key], dict_two[key]) for key in dict_one}` if you always have the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dict_one = {'average' : 84, 'median' : 86.5, 'stdev' : 3.35}
dict_two = {'average' : 'B', 'median' : 'B+', 'stdev' : 'F'}
ds = [dict_one, dict_two]
d = {}
for k in dict_one.keys():
    d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)

print(d)
```