# create a dictionary combining other dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

I have two dictionaries of the type:

```
dict1 = {NTID: (ID, CN)}

dict2 = {NTID: INCHI}
```

and I want to get:

```
dict3 = {NTID: (ID, CN, INCHI)}
```

I have tried to use zip, as follows:

```
dict_3 = dict(zip(dict1, dict2))
```

BUt I get NTID as keys and values. Please note that there are multiple values per each dictionary, but the order of the values between dict1 and dict2 is consistent

EDIT:

An example from dict1 is (keys: '1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL', '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE', 'ACETYLCHOLINE', 'ASN')

```
{'1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL': [],
 '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': [('24', 'gamma-aminobutyrate (GABA)'),
  ('172', 'alpha-ketoglutarate'),
  ('173', 'succinate'),
  ('399', 'Succinate semialdehyde'),
  ('111', 'putrescine'),
  ('114', '4-guanidinobutanoate'),
  ('115', '4-acetamidobutanoate')],
 'ACETYLCHOLINE': [],
 'ASN': [('1', 'glycine'),
  ('45', 'tyrosine'),
  ('74', 'leucine'),
  ('90', 'methionine'),
  ('80', 'valine')]}
```

dict2:

```
{'1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL': [],
 '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': ['InChI=1S/C4H9NO2/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h1-3,5H2,(H,6,7)',
  'InChI=1S/C5H6O5/c6-3(5(9)10)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-2',
  'InChI=1S/C4H6O4/c5-3(6)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,5,6)(H,7,8)/p-2',
  'InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h3H,1-2H2,(H,6,7)/p-1',
  'InChI=1S/C4H12N2/c5-3-1-2-4-6/h1-6H2/p+2',
  'InChI=1S/C5H11N3O2/c6-5(7)8-3-1-2-4(9)10/h1-3H2,(H,9,10)(H4,6,7,8)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H11NO3/c1-5(8)7-4-2-3-6(9)10/h2-4H2,1H3,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-1'],
 'ACETYLCHOLINE': [],
 'ASN': ['InChI=1S/C9H11NO3',
  'InChI=1S/C9H11NO2/c10-8',
  'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2/c1-2(4)3(5)6',
  'InChI=1S/C5H9NO2/c7-5(8)4-2-1-3',
  'InChI=1S/C4H9NO3/c1-2(6)3',
  'InChI=1S/C4H8N2O3/c5-2(4(8)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H13NO2/c1-3-4(2)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H9N3O2/c7-5(6(10)',
  'InChI=1S/C4H7NO4/c5-2(4(8)9)',
  'InChI=1S/C4H4O5/c5-2(4(8)9)1-',
  'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2S/c4-2(1-7)3(5)',
  'InChI=1S/C5H10N2O3/c6-3(5(9)'}
```

dict3 (output) should look like:

```
{'1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL': [],
 '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': [('24', 'gamma-aminobutyrate (GABA)', 'InChI=1S/C4H9NO2/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h1-3,5H2,(H,6,7)'),
  ('172', 'alpha-ketoglutarate', 'InChI=1S/C5H6O5/c6-3(5(9)10)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-2', 'InChI=1S/C4H6O4/c5-3(6)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,5,6)(H,7,8)/p-2'),
  ('173', 'succinate', 'InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h3H,1-2H2,(H,6,7)/p-1'),
  etc...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key)

Comment: `dict1['NTID'] += (dict2['NTID'],)`?

Comment: Should I put that in a for loop, to loop through each keys?

Comment: I have seen that post, but my post is not really the same case, because the value of one of my dictionary is a tuple, and I want my output dictionary to have tuples of three elements as value

Comment: [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5946322/8944057) there should give you an idea of how you would approach this. I'm not sure if there's a better way but the lack of better answers seems to suggest that iterating through both dictionaries is the best approach. Referring to the linked answer, for your specific case since `dict1` stores tuples, instead of `.append(value)`, you can use `.extend(value)` for when value is a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
dict1 = {'NTID': ('ID', 'CN')}

dict2 = {'NTID': 'INCHI'}


    final_dict={}
    for key,value in dict1.items():
        final_dict[key]=[value[0],value[1]]
        if key in dict2:
            final_dict[key].append(dict2.get(key))

    print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'NTID': ['ID', 'CN', 'INCHI']}
```

if you want result in tuple as you shown then:

```
final_dict={}
for key,value in dict1.items():
    final_dict[key]=value
    if key in dict2:
        final_dict[key]+=(dict2.get(key),)

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'NTID': ('ID', 'CN', 'INCHI')}
```

second you can use defaultdict:

```
dict1 = {'NTID': ('ID', 'CN')}

dict2 = {'NTID': 'INCHI'}

from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
for item in (dict1,dict2):
    for key,value in item.items():
        d[key].append(value)

print(d)
```

> Updated as per question edit :

```
dict_1={'1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL': [],
 '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': [('24', 'gamma-aminobutyrate (GABA)'),
  ('172', 'alpha-ketoglutarate'),
  ('173', 'succinate'),
  ('399', 'Succinate semialdehyde'),
  ('111', 'putrescine'),
  ('114', '4-guanidinobutanoate'),
  ('115', '4-acetamidobutanoate')],
 'ACETYLCHOLINE': [],
 'ASN': [('1', 'glycine'),
  ('45', 'tyrosine'),
  ('74', 'leucine'),
  ('90', 'methionine'),
  ('80', 'valine')]}



dict_2={'1-4-HYDROXYPHENYL': [],
 '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': ['InChI=1S/C4H9NO2/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h1-3,5H2,(H,6,7)',
  'InChI=1S/C5H6O5/c6-3(5(9)10)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-2',
  'InChI=1S/C4H6O4/c5-3(6)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,5,6)(H,7,8)/p-2',
  'InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h3H,1-2H2,(H,6,7)/p-1',
  'InChI=1S/C4H12N2/c5-3-1-2-4-6/h1-6H2/p+2',
  'InChI=1S/C5H11N3O2/c6-5(7)8-3-1-2-4(9)10/h1-3H2,(H,9,10)(H4,6,7,8)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H11NO3/c1-5(8)7-4-2-3-6(9)10/h2-4H2,1H3,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-1'],
 'ACETYLCHOLINE': [],
 'ASN': ['InChI=1S/C9H11NO3',
  'InChI=1S/C9H11NO2/c10-8',
  'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2/c1-2(4)3(5)6',
  'InChI=1S/C5H9NO2/c7-5(8)4-2-1-3',
  'InChI=1S/C4H9NO3/c1-2(6)3',
  'InChI=1S/C4H8N2O3/c5-2(4(8)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H13NO2/c1-3-4(2)',
  'InChI=1S/C6H9N3O2/c7-5(6(10)',
  'InChI=1S/C4H7NO4/c5-2(4(8)9)',
  'InChI=1S/C4H4O5/c5-2(4(8)9)1-',
  'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2S/c4-2(1-7)3(5)',
  'InChI=1S/C5H10N2O3/c6-3(5(9)']}


final_dict={}
for key,value in dict_1.items():
    if key in dict_2:
        for zip_value in zip(value,dict_2.get(key)):
            if key not in final_dict:
                final_dict[key]=[zip_value]
            else:
                final_dict[key].append(zip_value)



print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'ASN': [(('1', 'glycine'), 'InChI=1S/C9H11NO3'), (('45', 'tyrosine'), 'InChI=1S/C9H11NO2/c10-8'), (('74', 'leucine'), 'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2/c1-2(4)3(5)6'), (('90', 'methionine'), 'InChI=1S/C5H9NO2/c7-5(8)4-2-1-3'), (('80', 'valine'), 'InChI=1S/C4H9NO3/c1-2(6)3')], '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': [(('24', 'gamma-aminobutyrate (GABA)'), 'InChI=1S/C4H9NO2/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h1-3,5H2,(H,6,7)'), (('172', 'alpha-ketoglutarate'), 'InChI=1S/C5H6O5/c6-3(5(9)10)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-2'), (('173', 'succinate'), 'InChI=1S/C4H6O4/c5-3(6)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,5,6)(H,7,8)/p-2'), (('399', 'Succinate semialdehyde'), 'InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h3H,1-2H2,(H,6,7)/p-1'), (('111', 'putrescine'), 'InChI=1S/C4H12N2/c5-3-1-2-4-6/h1-6H2/p+2'), (('114', '4-guanidinobutanoate'), 'InChI=1S/C5H11N3O2/c6-5(7)8-3-1-2-4(9)10/h1-3H2,(H,9,10)(H4,6,7,8)'), (('115', '4-acetamidobutanoate'), 'InChI=1S/C6H11NO3/c1-5(8)7-4-2-3-6(9)10/h2-4H2,1H3,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-1')]}
```

> Little modifed if you don't want those extra brackets :

```
final_dict={}
for key,value in dict_1.items():
    if key in dict_2:
        for zip_value in zip(value,dict_2.get(key)):

            if key not in final_dict:
                final_dict[key]=[zip_value[0][0],zip_value[0][1],zip_value[1]]
            else:
                final_dict[key].append((zip_value[0][0],zip_value[0][1],zip_value[1]))



print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'ASN': ['1', 'glycine', 'InChI=1S/C9H11NO3', ('45', 'tyrosine', 'InChI=1S/C9H11NO2/c10-8'), ('74', 'leucine', 'InChI=1S/C3H7NO2/c1-2(4)3(5)6'), ('90', 'methionine', 'InChI=1S/C5H9NO2/c7-5(8)4-2-1-3'), ('80', 'valine', 'InChI=1S/C4H9NO3/c1-2(6)3')], '4-AMINO-BUTYRATE': ['24', 'gamma-aminobutyrate (GABA)', 'InChI=1S/C4H9NO2/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h1-3,5H2,(H,6,7)', ('172', 'alpha-ketoglutarate', 'InChI=1S/C5H6O5/c6-3(5(9)10)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-2'), ('173', 'succinate', 'InChI=1S/C4H6O4/c5-3(6)1-2-4(7)8/h1-2H2,(H,5,6)(H,7,8)/p-2'), ('399', 'Succinate semialdehyde', 'InChI=1S/C4H6O3/c5-3-1-2-4(6)7/h3H,1-2H2,(H,6,7)/p-1'), ('111', 'putrescine', 'InChI=1S/C4H12N2/c5-3-1-2-4-6/h1-6H2/p+2'), ('114', '4-guanidinobutanoate', 'InChI=1S/C5H11N3O2/c6-5(7)8-3-1-2-4(9)10/h1-3H2,(H,9,10)(H4,6,7,8)'), ('115', '4-acetamidobutanoate', 'InChI=1S/C6H11NO3/c1-5(8)7-4-2-3-6(9)10/h2-4H2,1H3,(H,7,8)(H,9,10)/p-1')]}
```

Comment: mmm... my output looks a bit different: I get a dictionary like {'NTID'1: (('ID1', 'CN1'), ('ID2', 'CN2'), ('ID3', 'CN3')) ['INCHI1','INCHI2', 'INCHI3' ])}

Comment: @smvpfm i gave you answer on data which you provided to me. give me sample data of your actual data so i can look the issue.

Comment: Sure thing, I inserted an example of my dictionaries

Comment: not exactly my output should be a dictionary with lists of tuples, please check my update

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict3 = {name: [(*a, b) for a, b in zip(v, dict2[name])]
    for name, v in dict1.items()
}
```

From what I understand, `dict1` and `dict2` have the same keys and structure but are storing different information related to the same one thing, and you want to merge them both into a common `dict3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3 = dict(zip(dict1.keys(), zip(dict1.values(),dict2.values())))
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments or context around how the code addresses the original question.