# How can I compare value of one dictionary to another and get that value?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm currently parsing through JSON as a quick example this is what it looks like:

Dictionary 1:

```
data:
    0:
        tag "importanttagone"
        value   233
    1:  
        tag "importanttagtwo"
        value   234
```

Dictionary 2:

```
data:
    0:
        name    "Important Tag One"
        tag     "importanttagone"
    1:
        name    "Important Tag Two"
        tag     "importanttagtwo"
```

So essentially what I want is to display the name and the value associated.

```
Expected Output:

Name: Important Tag On

Value: 233
```

Is there a way to compare both tags in the dictionaries and then get the name that's within the same key as the tag?

Comment: Could you provide expected output?

Comment: @Alexey My apologies. I added it

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {
    "data":{
        0: {
            "tag": "importanttagone",
            "value": 233
        },
        1: {
            "tag": "importanttagtwo",
            "value": 234
        }
    }
}

d2 = {
    "data":{
        0: {
            "tag": "importanttagone",
            "name": "Important Tag One"
        },
        1: {
            "tag": "importanttagtwo",
            "name": "Important Tag Two"
        }
    }
}

d1_flat = {v['tag']: v['value'] for _, v in d1['data'].items()}
d2_flat = {v['tag']: v['name'] for _, v in d2['data'].items()}

result = {}

for k, v in d1_flat.items():
    name = d2_flat.get(k, None)
    if name:
        result[name] = v

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'Important Tag One': 233, 'Important Tag Two': 234}
```

Comment: I get a:        

    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `get` gives you `None` for free. No need to write it as a second argument.

Comment: Also, if you don't use the dict keys, you simply could use `for v in d1['data'].values()`. Other than that, your solution is more efficient than the others.

Answer (score 0):

If the same tags has the same keys in the dicts:

```
[(d1[key]['name'], d2[key]['value']) for key in d1 if key in d2]
```

Answer (score 0):

compare the two dictionaries maybe element-wise by iteration through both dicts:

```
for k1 in dict1:
   for k2 in dict2:
      if dict1[k1]['tag'] == dict2[k2]['tag']
         print('Name  : ' + dict[k1]['name'])
         print('Value : ' + dict[k2]['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this before and I always get:


 '  
KeyError: 'tag'    '

Comment: I added ['data'] to the first two lines.

for k1 in dict1['data']:
   for k2 in dict2['data']:


but now i get: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about your dictionary structure. is it like the one explained by @Alexey ? You have 2 dicts, dict1 and dict2 with the same tags? ever considered putting it in one and the same dict, since you are just doubling your necessary memory?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. Firefox listed it like that, however, Chrome doesn't have those 0,1,2...etc. Is it possible to combine dictionaries that are parsed from the internet? I didn't even think about that. The problem with that is one dictionary has more keys than the other

Comment: have a look at that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5946359/7813847
same approach as for efficient SQL databases

Answer (score 0):

> You can try One line solution :

```
#data from @Alexey

d1 = {
    "data":{
        0: {
            "tag": "importanttagone",
            "value": 233
        },
        1: {
            "tag": "importanttagtwo",
            "value": 234
        }
    }
}

d2 = {
    "data":{
        0: {
            "tag": "importanttagone",
            "name": "Important Tag One"
        },
        1: {
            "tag": "importanttagtwo",
            "name": "Important Tag Two"
        }
    }
}

print({item.get('value'):sub_item.get('name') for item in d1['data'].values()for sub_item in d2['data'].values()if item.get('tag') in sub_item.values()})
```

> output:

```
{233: 'Important Tag One', 234: 'Important Tag Two'}
```