# Consolidate python dictionary

Tags: python

I need help converting these dictionaries to a single dictionary. See below

```
data = [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 5, 'y': 3}, {'x': 1, 'y': 4}]
```

I want to convert it to below:

```
{'x':[3,5,1], 'y':[3,3,4]
```

thank you!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key) is a more accurate dupe, mind if I change it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes sir, please do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 5, 'y': 3}, {'x': 1, 'y': 4}]
new_data = {i:[c.get(i) for c in data] for i in ['x', 'y']}
```

Output:

```
{'y': [3, 3, 4], 'x': [3, 5, 1]}
```

However, to be more generic, you can use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
new_result = {
    i : [c.get(i) for c in data] 
    for i in set(reduce(
      lambda x, y:list(getattr(x, 'keys', lambda :x)()) + list(y.keys()), data)
   )
}
```

Edit: shorter generic solution:

```
new_s = {i for b in map(dict.keys, data) for i in b}
new_data = {i:[c.get(i) for c in data] for i in new_s}
```

Comment: Good answer, upvoted.

Comment: I would iterate over `data.keys()` instead of `[x, y]` for a generic solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Good point. I just added another generic possibility, but I will add yours with plain `dict.keys` as well.

Comment: Not a fan of the reduce solution. ;-/ However, if you're going to insist on one-liners, you should strive to at least obey PEP-8. For example, you can always break it into multiple lines for readability. :)

Comment: No, not like that. See [here](http://dpaste.com/214EAVH).

Comment: Last nitpick: PEP-8 recommends 4 spaces for indent (not 2). Keep it up, and you'll be seeing a lot more +10s from me ;-)

Comment: @Aran-Fey fixed. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do it:

```
data = [{'x': 3, 'y': 3}, {'x': 5, 'y': 3}, {'x': 1, 'y': 4}]


emptyX = []
emptyY = []

for i in data:
    emptyX.append(i['x'])
    emptyY.append(i['y'])

final = {'x':emptyX, 'y':emptyY}

print(final)
```

Here you just create two empty lists. One to store the `x` values and one to store the `y` values and then add the value of each dictionary while the `for`loop initerates through the list.