# Transform list of Pandas DataFrames to nested dictionary with values as lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have an ordered list of pandas dataframes, each contains data for a given year:

```
yearly_data_list = [df_2000, df_2001, ... , df_2010]
```

These dataframes have the same shape, say R rows and C columns, and the same column names and index.

I want to create N = R*C time series of length `len(yearly_data_list)`, one for each entry in the dataframes and put them into a nested dictionary where the final value is the list. For a given entry in the dataframes, the first value of the corresponding list would be the entry of `df_2000`, the second value the entry `df_2001`, etc.

For example, say I have N=3 dataframes with 2 rows (R=2) and 3 columns (C=3) each:

```
df_2000 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]], columns=list('ABC'), index=list('xy'))

   A   B   C
x  12  13  14
y  15  16  17

df_2001 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]], columns=list('ABC'), index=list('xy'))

   A   B   C
x  6   7   8
y  9  10  11

df_2002 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], columns=list('ABC'), index=list('xy'))

   A  B  C
x  0  1  2
y  3  4  5
```

In this case, I would like to obtain R*C=6 lists (time series) of length 3 and put the inside a nested dictionary that looks something like:

```
{'x': {'A': [12, 6, 0], 'B': [13, 7, 1], 'C': [14, 8, 2]},
 'y': {'A': [15, 9, 3], 'B': [16, 10, 4], 'C': [17, 11, 5]}}
```

Note that on the outermost level the keys come from the index and in the innermost level the keys come from the column names.

I know that with `pd.Dataframe.T.to_dict()` I could get 3 dictionaries that look like this but contain the individual values for each dataframe instead of the lists. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key) SO answer they merge multiple dictionaries but I have not been able to make it work for my nested dictionary case.

Any help using the link's approach, or any other, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `concat` and `groupby`:

```
(pd.concat([df_2000, df_2001, df_2002])
   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
   .to_dict('index')
 )
```

Output:

```
{'x': {'A': [12, 6, 0], 'B': [13, 7, 1], 'C': [14, 8, 2]},
 'y': {'A': [15, 9, 3], 'B': [16, 10, 4], 'C': [17, 11, 5]}}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Will accept it as soon as SO allows me to.