# How to append column when compared columns are equal

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two lists that I need to merge based on a column name that exists in both. The source is JSON.
I'm not sure how to do this, I looked at [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key#) but that one doesn't constrain anything.

Example:

```
dict1 = {"a": 3, 'b': 4}
dict2 = {"a": 3, 'c': 5}
dict3 = {"a": 1, 'b': 2}
dict4 = {"a": 1, 'c': 8}

dict_result = [{"a": 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5},{"a": 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 8}]
```

BR

Comment: Do you always want only 3 elements in the dictionary?  Can you also add the expected O/P when there are no duplicate elements?

Comment: I have some 500+ rows but yes the columns would always be the same. But I was hoping to find a way to add new columns where a reference column compares which order the elements would be added. I can do it an MS Excel, but having issues here

Comment: I have an answer. I am not sure whether that is correct. Do you mind checking it?

Comment: @JacksonPro where would I see this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this.

```py
dict1 = {"a": 3, 'b': 4}
dict2 = {"a": 3, 'c': 5}
dict3 = {"a": 1, 'b': 2}
dict4 = {"a": 1, 'c': 8}

def merge_dictionary(*args):
    dictionary = []
    dict_result=[]
    app_index = 0 # append index

    for dic in (args):
        for item, value in dic.items():
            if [item, value] not in dictionary:
                dictionary.append([item, value])


    for index, x in enumerate(dictionary):
        
        if index%3==0: 
            dict_result.append({x[0]:x[1]})
            app_index = index
       
        else:
            dict_result[app_index//3].update({x[0]:x[1]})

    return dict_result

print(merge_dictionary(dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4))
```