# Merging two dictionaries with duplicate keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get the dictionary from two lists

```
keys = [1, 1, 2]
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

I expect the result would be like this

```
dictionary1 = {1: 1, 2, 2:3}
```

I tried to do

```
for i, j in zip(keys, values):
    dictionary1[i].append(j)
```

but it did not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge dicts, collecting values from matching keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-dicts-collecting-values-from-matching-keys)

Comment: having a dict of `{1: 1,2, 2:3}` isn't possible as it does not fit dictionary syntax. If you are looking for a contained list or other iterable such as `{1:[1,2], 2:[3]}` that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support duplicate keys. So when a two particular lists are converted to a dictionary like :

```
keys = [1, 1, 2]
values = [1, 2, 3]
dictionary1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dictionary1)
```

It will output only the latest reference given to it.

```
{1: 2, 2: 3}
```