# Python: NLTK: access element of list of list

Tags: python, nltk

I have following list of lists, as a result after tokenizing:

```
[['Who', 'are', 'you', '?'],
 ['I', 'do', 'not', 'know', 'who', 'you', 'are'],
 ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name', '?']]
```

Now I would like to have a list containing the "simple" elements, e.g.:

```
['Who','are','you','?','I','do','not','know','who'...]
```

I have already tried everything I could possibly think of, using (nested) for loops, (nested) while loops... I either get the list `['Who','Who','Who',...]` (and so on) or I get `"list index out of range"`.

Can somebody please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: In other words, you want to flatten the list of lists? See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python), or in your simpler case, just `sum(lst, [])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flatten an (irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python nested list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) function in python

```
In [1]: a= [['Who', 'are', 'you', '?'], ['I', 'do', 'not', 'know', 'who', 'you', 'are'], ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name', '?']]
In [2]: b = []
In [3]: for list_ in a:
    b.extend(list_)
   ...:     

In [4]: b
Out[4]: ['Who','are','you','?','I','do', ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

Python >=2.6, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` which doesn't require unpacking the list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list2d = [["who", "are", "you", "?"]....]
>>> merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to merge the list?

```
flat_list = []
for list_item in nested_list:
    flat_list += list_item

>>flat_list
>>['Who', 'are', 'you', '?', 'I', 'do', 'not', 'know', 'who', 'you', 'are', 'What', 'is', 'your', 'name', '?']
```

A possible duplicate can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

just for the record when seeing other answers, a more pythonic way is to use a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18072799/1176601), like this:

```
original_list = [[1], [2, 3]]
flat_list = [i for sublist in original_list for i in sublist]
```