# Python: how to parallelize a loop with dictionary

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, mapping

EDITED: I have a code which looks like:

```
__author__ = 'feynman'

cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def MC_Surface(volume, mc_vol):

    Perm_area = {
        "00000000": 0.000000,
        "11111111": 0.000000,
         ...
         ...
        "11100010": 1.515500,
        "00011101": 1.515500
    }

    cdef int j, i, k
    for k in range(volume.shape[2] - 1):
        for j in range(volume.shape[1] - 1):
            for i in range(volume.shape[0] - 1):

                pattern = '%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i' % (
                    volume[i, j, k],
                    volume[i, j + 1, k],
                    volume[i + 1, j, k],
                    volume[i + 1, j + 1, k],
                    volume[i, j, k + 1],
                    volume[i, j + 1, k + 1],
                    volume[i + 1, j, k + 1],
                    volume[i + 1, j + 1, k + 1])

                mc_vol[i, j, k] = Perm_area[pattern]

    return mc_vol
```

In the hope to speed up, it was modified to:

```
    {
      ...
      ...
      "11100010": 1.515500,
      "00011101": 1.515500
    }
    keys = np.array(Perm_area.keys())
    values = np.array(Perm_area.values())

    starttime = time.time()
    tmp_vol = GetPattern(volume)
    print 'time to populate the key array: ', time.time() - starttime

    cdef int i
    starttime=time.time()
    for i, this_key in enumerate(keys):
        mc_vol[tmp_vol == this_key] = values[i]

    print 'time for the loop: ', time.time() -starttime
    return mc_vol

def GetPattern(volume):
    a = (volume.astype(np.int)).astype(np.str)
    output = a.copy()  # Central voxel
    output[:, :-1, :] = np.char.add(output[:, :-1, :], a[:, 1:, :])  # East
    output[:-1, :, :] = np.char.add(output[:-1, :, :], a[1:, :, :])  # South
    output[:-1, :-1, :] = np.char.add(output[:-1, :-1, :], a[1:, 1:, :])  # SouthEast
    output[:, :, :-1] = np.char.add(output[:, :, :-1], a[:, :, 1:])  # Down
    output[:, :-1, :-1] = np.char.add(output[:, :-1, :-1], a[:, 1:, 1:])  # DownEast
    output[:-1, :, :-1] = np.char.add(output[:-1, :, :-1], a[1:, :, 1:])  # DownSouth
    output[:-1, :-1, :-1] = np.char.add(output[:-1, :-1, :-1], a[1:, 1:, 1:])  # DownSouthEast
    output = output[:-1, :-1, :-1]
    del a
    return output
```

This takes longer for a 3D array of size say 500^3. Here, tmp_vol 3D array of strings. For example: if say tmp_vol[0,0,0] = "00000000" then mc_vol[0,0,0] = 0.00000. Alternatively, I can get rid of mc_vol and write if tmp_vol[0,0,0] = "00000000" then tmp_vol[0,0,0] = 0.00000.

Here, The for-loop takes a lot of time, I see that only one CPU is used. I tried to map them in parallel using map and lambda but ran into errors. I am really new to python so any hints will be great.

Comment: Could explain better what your code actually does? What is tmp_vol?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! tmp_vol has the keys like in the dictionary Perm_area = { "00000000": 0.000000, ... ... ... "11100010": 1.515500, "00011101": 1.515500 }. After tmp_vol is populated with the keys, the keys are to be replaced by the corresponding values in dictionary Perm_area at their respective position in 3D array. For example: if say tmp_vol[0,0,0] = "00000000" then mc_vol[0,0,0] = 0.00000. Alternatively, if tmp_vol[0,0,0] = "00000000" then tmp_vol[0,0,0] = 0.00000 is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't quite understand your code and you said "any hints will be great", I'll give you some general suggestions. Basically you want to speed up a for loop

```
for i, this_key in enumerate(keys):
```

What you could do is split the `keys` array into several parts, something like this:

```
length = len(keys)
part1 = keys[:length/3]
part2 = keys[length/3: 2*length/3]
part3 = keys[2*length/3:]
```

Then deal with each part in a subprocess:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def do_work(keys):
    for i, this_key in enumerate(keys): 
        mc_vol[tmp_vol == this_key] = values[i]

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as e:
    e.submit(do_work, part1)
    e.submit(do_work, part2)
    e.submit(do_work, part3)

return mc_vol
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it out right now. I included the full code in my question.

Comment: I tried to separate in parts as you suggested. The memory usage increases and eventually program runs out of memory.

Comment: Then your program may have problems. I don't have much time to fully understand your program, but using multiprocessing would not cause such error if your program is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, dictionary lookup takes closely constant time, although array equality check is O(N). Thus you should loop over your array and not your dictionary.

Second, you could save much time with [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension) (change python loop to C loop).

```
mc_vol = [[Perm_area[key] for key in row] for row in tmp_vol]
```

This gives you a list of lists, so you can completely avoid numpy in this case. Although if you need a numpy array, just convert:

```
mc_vol = np.array(mc_vol)
```

Comment: Vectorized version takes long time as well and eventually runs out memory. For-Loop version seems ok with memory but is slow, however not much slower than vectorized version.