# Understanding evaluation order of nested list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I am preparing for my exam and I decided to start solving past exams. One of the requirements is to understand what a code does. But I am having troubles with this annotation.

I do not understand which the structure of this nested loop and which loop is executed first.

```
n = 10
p = [q for q in range(2, n) if q not in [r for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)) for r in range(i * 2, n, i)]]
print(p)
```

Can someone help me understand please?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension) help?

Comment: write them out as regular loops and you will be able to figure it out pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

It starts by evaluating:

```
[r for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)) for r in range(i * 2, n, i)]
```

which boils down to:

```
[r for r in range(4, 10, 2)]
```

since `range(2, int(n * 0.5))` reduces to a list with a single element `[2]` that is used as the value of `i` in the `for r in range(i * 2, n, i)` statement. So the inner list comprehension evaluates to `[4, 6, 8]`.

Then, the outer loop `for q in range(2, n)` is executed and it returns those elements from the list `[2, 3, ..., 9]` that do not belong in the previously constructed list i.e `[4, 6, 8]` with:

```
# range(2, n) -> [2, 3, ..., 9]
q for q in range(2, n) if q not in [..previously constructed list]
```

Comment: alright I get it cristal clear now!! thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, the innermost loops are going to be executed first.

Having this in mind, let's break the problem down :

```
[r for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)) for r in range(i * 2, n, i)]
```

`n**0.5` is 3.xxx, so `range(2, int(n**0.5))` is in fact range(2, 3), which is 2 (see [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) for more informations).

So `i` is going to be 2, no matter what.

`r in range(i * 2, n, i)` looks pretty simple now, r will be between 4 and 10 (excluded), using a step of 2. The possible values are 4, 6 and 8.

The problem becomes :

```
p = [q for q in range(2, n) if q not in [4, 6, 8]]
```

Which is basically all odd numbers between 2 and 10 (excluded), plus the number 2.

Answer (score 0):

This equivalent to :

```
list_i=[]
for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)):
    for r in range(i*2, n, i):
        list_i.append(r)
res=[]
for q in range(2, n) :
    if q not in list_i:
        res.append(q)

print res
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're having a hard time understanding inner loops, run this code:

```
resultA = []
for x in ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']:
    for y in ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']:
        for z in ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']:
            resultA.append(''.join([x, y, z]))

print resultA

resultB = [''.join([x, y, z])
           for x in ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
           for y in ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']
           for z in ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']
           ]

print resultB

print resultA == resultB
```

Once you've understood this code comprehension lists become second nature to you, then just come back to your original code and you won't have any problems with it :)