# List comprehensions Conversion

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, defaultdict

i started learning Python recently and i am facing difficulty converting the below piece of code into a list comprehension:

```
    list = []     #An empty List
    for key,value in defaultDict.items():#iterate through the default dict
        for i in defaultDict[key]:#iterate through the list in the defaultDict
            if i not in list:#If the item in the list is not present in the main list
                list.append(i)#append it
```

Is it possible for me to even do it??Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: you already have the value, no need for the inner loop

Comment: @self: OP will need an inner loop. It seems that `value` is itself a list

Comment: `value` is a list, sure, but he should use `value` instead of a key lookup

Comment: That is absolutely true. That second loop should be `for i in value`

Comment: @self :Yes, i should have!!I realized it after reading your comment!!I am very new to python, so it dint flash that i could do it!!Thanks a lot for the comment though!!Now i know two better ways to meet my goals!!Lol!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very straightforward: use a nested list comprehension to get all `i`s and a set to remove duplicates.

```
list(set([item for __, value in defaultDict.items() for item in value]))
```

Let's break it down:

- `[item for key,value in defaultDict.items() for item in value]` is a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension).
- `set(...)` will remove all duplicates - the equivalent of `if i not in list: list.append(i)` logic you have
- `list(set(...))` will convert the set back to a list for you.

Comment: Wow!!This solution is so compact and nice!!Awesome man!!Thanks for breaking it up!!So perfect

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Sure!!I couldn't accept it due to the time restriction. I will go ahead and do it right away!!