# How to measure the length of a word of a phrase in a list

Tags: python

How I can measure the length of single words in a phrase in a list in python?
If I write:

```
>>> lst=['Hi Andrea how are you','Happy birthday']
>>> print(len(lst))
5
```

I need this:

```
>>> [ 2 6 3 3 3 , 5 8 ]
```

The single measure of a single words.

Answer (score 2):

*Moses Koledoye beat me to it, but here's a more detailed answer to (hopefully) help you learn.*

In your example, you could loop through the list and count the lengths of each individual word. This will require separating out the words in each sentence.

A simple way to get individual words from a string sentence is to use Python's **`split()`**. This will split up the text based on whitespace (or given characters) and return the results in a list:

```
>>> 'Hi Andrea how are you'.split()
['Hi', 'Andrea', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Then to find the length of each word, use **`len()`**:

```
>>> len('hi')
2
```

Using [**list comprehension**](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (as seen in Moses' answer), you can combine these together in a nice succinct way:

```
[[len(word) for word in sentence.split()] for sentence in lst]
```

Since list comprehensions can get confusing, this is what it might look like fully written out:

```
all_lens = []
for sentence in lst:
    word_lens = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        word_lens.append(len(word))
    all_lens.append(word_lens)
print(all_lens)     
[[2, 6, 3, 3, 3], [5, 8]]
```

Now you can see why using a list comprehension instead is a lot nicer (though sometimes more confusing).

For more background on nested list comprehension in Python, see this related question: [python nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension)

Comment: Great explanation. Very detailed considering your current reputation. Have a great journey at SO

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're up to. Use a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> lst=['Hi Andrea how are you','Happy birthday']
>>> [[len(i) for i in x.split()] for x in lst]
[[2, 6, 3, 3, 3], [5, 8]]
```

This gives the lengths in a list of lists.

Comment: I have two variables a = 1 and b = 3 and I have to find words that have sizes between a and b in the list, how can I?

Comment: That's another problem.You should post that as a new question.