# list comprehension filtering files in a list of directories

Tags: python

sel_dirs is a list of user supplied directories in which to search for .xlsx files:

```
results_excels = []
for each_dir in sel_dirs:
    for each_file in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(my_dir, each_dir))):
        if each_file.endswith("_Results.xlsx"):
                results_excels.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(my_dir, each_dir, each_file)))
```

What is the cleanest way to gather a list of all of the Results Excel files within the directories supplied by the list, possibly with a list comprehension which can be evaluated on a **list** of directories, and not simply on one directory?

i.e.

```
results_excels = [filename for filename in os.listdir(LIST) if filename.endswith("_Results.xlsx")]
```

Where LIST is the sel_dirs list of directories and not just one directory?

Comment: The _cleanest_ is probably the way you did it first. You *can* turn it into a [nested comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/python-nested-list-comprehension), but that'll be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The question boils down to: how to make a list of lists into one list? Because `.listdir()` returns a list, you cannot do a simple comprehension.

Meet `itertools.chain`. It picks a list of iterables and iterates over them sequentially, which is what a comprehension needs.
The only detail is that `listdir`'s values need to be prepended with dir's path, else it's lost.

```
import itertools

files_in_dir = lambda d: [os.path.join(d, fname) for fname in os.listdir(d)] 
file_lists = [files_in_dir(d) for d in sel_dirs]
all_files = itertools.chain(*file_lists)
excel_files = [f for f in all_files if f.endswith('.xlsx')]
```