# List comprenhension help python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand better the list comprehension:

I have the following code:

```
deck = [] 
for rank in ranks:
    for suit in suits:
        deck.append(('%s%s')%(rank, suit))
```

How can I transform in list comprehension?
And is it more pythonic to have as list comprehension or not?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list][1]

Answer (score 1):

```
ranks = [1,2,3,4,5]
suits = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

deck = [] 
for rank in ranks:
    for suit in suits:
        deck.append(('%s%s')%(rank, suit))


deck_comp = [('%s%s')%(rank, suit) for rank in ranks for suit in suits]

print(deck == deck_comp)
```