# Convert Single line loop into multiple line loop Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am having trouble with convert this single line loop into multiple line code in python.

```
text_data = [''.join(char for char in sent if char not in punct) for sent in text_data]
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

solved it.

```
out_list = []
for sent in test_data:
    out_str = ''
    for char in sent:
        if char not in punct:
            out_str = out_str+char
    out_list.append(out_str)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Why are you having trouble? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Also, have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if I tried at all. Btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following snippet for your nested one line for loop

```
out_list = []
for sent in text_data:
    out_str = ''
    for char in sent:
        if char not in punct:
            out_str.join(char)
    out_list.append(out_str)
```