# Nested for loop in Single Line

Tags: python

I have a logic need to count the iteration

```
counts = []
for .. in ..:
    count = 0
    for .. in ..:
        if ..:
            count +=1
    counts.append(count)
```

How to change this logic into single line loop in python

Comment: Can you provide the full nested structure?

Comment: this is my nested structure, In condition I have dataframe column data

Comment: 1. What purpose would you have for putting a nested loop in a single line? Just curiosity? 2. This is difficult to answer when all of your conditions and variables are `...`. 3. You probably want a list comprehension inside a list comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum()` with nested list comprehensions:

```
counts = [sum([1 for c in b if p(c)]) for b in a]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
counts = []
for b in a:
    count = 0
    for c in b:
        if p(c):
            count = count + 1
    counts.append(count)
```

Comment: or `counts = [sum(p(c) for c in b) for b in a]` (abuses the fact that `bool` subclasses `int` and also doesn't create an intermediate list) to save a tiny bit of memory

Comment: @DeepSpace Hey nice I like it :). Only works if `p(c)` returns a Boolean type though (True/False)

Comment: @TerryA indeed, or 0/1.