# Listing 2 items at once using short version of list-making python

Tags: python

Is there a way to list 2 items at one line using the short version of making lists.

For example I want to write something like

```
G3 = [(i,j) for i in Primes and j in G2 if dig_sum(i,j) == True and con_test(i,j) == True ]
```

**Edit: I should have mentioned this gives me error of**

```
NameError: name 'j' is not defined


here i is an int and j is tuple
```

My main purpose is to get something like

```
G = [(i,j,k),(g,h,k)...]
```

I know that my uppser code will give something like

```
G = [(i,(j,k)),(g,(h,k))...]
```

but I can change it later I guess.

Here is the long version

```
G3 = []
for i in Primes:
    for j in G2:
        if dig_sum(i,j) == True and con_test(i,j) == True:
            G3.append((i,j[0],j[1]))
print(G3)
```

Comment: Why can't you use `G3 = [(i,j[0],j[1]) for i in Primes and j in G2 if dig_sum(i,j) and con_test(i,j)]` ?

Comment: "short versino of list-making" is called "list comprehension." That terminology might help you find what you're looking for in a google search. If not, here's a shortcut: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list

Comment: `for i in Primes and j in G2` is not valid Python. Read up on how to do it properly using the link above.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack in the tuple literal using `*` and switch out `and` for `for` to have a nested for loop in a list comprehension. You also don't need `== True` in an `if` block.

```
G3 = [(i,*j) for i in Primes for j in G2 if dig_sum(i,j) and con_test(i,j)]
```

n.b. this may not work in older versions of python. I'm not sure when it was introduced.

Comment: re: "not sure when it was introdcued": at least a long time ago: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Python 3.5 wasn't that long ago :)

Comment: The statement "You also don't need `== True` in an `if` block" is true in many contexts, but given that we know little about `dig_sum` and `con_test`, it is rather bold. `if x:` and `if x == True:` test very different things.

Comment: @schwobaseggl true, but I think it's fair to assume this is a beginners mistake and not a type check.