# Converting for loop to list comprehension is generating incorrect result

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
student = [['benny', 12.09], ['harry', 40.03], ['jenny', 56.03], ['garry', 56.33]]
for items in student:
    for _ in range(len(items)):
        if items[1] not in allscores:
          allscores.append(items[1])
print allscores
```

Output of the code above is

```
[12.09, 40.03, 56.03, 56.33]
```

as expected.

But if I turn the 2 `for` loops to a list comprehension,

```
allscores = [items[1] for _ in range(len(items)) if items[1] not in allscores for items in student]
print allscores
```

I get:

```
allscores = [items[1] for _ in range(len(items)) if items[1] not in allscores for items in student]
NameError: name 'items' is not defined
```

What is wrong in my list comprehension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294

Comment: `allscores = list(set([items[1] for items in student]))` You don't need to have a nested for loop if you already know the index of what you're looking for

Comment: Why do you have nested loops in the first place? There's no point in repeating the `items[1] not in allscores` test multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get the error is that loops in a double comprehension like that are written in the same order as a for loop. In particular,

```
a = []
for y in z:
    for x in y:
        a.append(x)
```

could be rewritten as

```
a = [x for y in z for x in y]
```

NOT as

```
a = [x for x in y for y in z]
```

The syntax you are probably thinking of is for a nested comprehension:

```
a = [[x for x in y] for y in z]
```

But that creates a 2D list, which is definitely *not* what you want here.

Now to answer your actual question, let's start with `items[1] for _ in range(len(items))`. You are literally checking `items[1]` twice for each element in your list. There may have been an attempt to ensure that the sub-list has two elements, but you killed it when you explicitly indexed element `1`.

Now you'd think that you can truncate your comprehension to

```
allscores = [items[1] for items in students if items[1] not in allscores]
```

But you can't. Remember that until the comprehension completes, `allscores` is undefined. Pre-initializing it to an empty list won't help either because it will stay empty until the comprehension completes.

The solution is to use a `set`. It's much more efficient than the linear lookup you are trying to do every time with the `in` operator in `if items[1] not in allscores`. It can also be used with a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to avoid storing the unnecessary elements:

```
allscores = set(items[1] for items in students)
```

Notice the lack of surrounding square brackets. If you absolutely need a list, do

```
allscores = list(set(items[1] for items in students))
```