# Nested list comprehension with if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get my head around nested list comprehension and have read the excellent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list).

The problem I'm having translating is that I've an `if` clause in my inner loop and I can't see how to apply this to the `func()` step as I'm loosing the counter I get from `enumerate()` when I go from nested loops to list comprehension.

```
nested_list = [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}], [{'a': 5, 'b': 6}, {'c': 7, 'd': 8}]]
new_list = []
for c, x in enumerate(nested_list):
    for d, y in enumerate(x):
        if d == 1:
            new_list.append(y)
print(new_list)
[{'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'c': 7, 'd': 8}]
```

Nested list comprehension might look something like

```
new_list = [if ??? y
               for x in nested_list
                   for y in x]
```

...but I can't see/think how to get the clause as I have no counter under the nested list comprehension.

Is there a way of achieving this or should I stick to the nested loops approach?

Comment: List comprehensions use the *same nesting order*, left to right. Move the `if` to the same location, don't put it in the value expression.

Comment: And you dropped the `enumerate()` function call, now you don't *have* a `d` variable to test with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes the loss of `d` in the second enumerate is the crux of my problem.  I'll give yours and t@Jean-FrancoisFabre suggestion a whirl, thanks.

Comment: @Sayse I believe list comprehension is a more "pythonic" way of doing things and will give cleaner more maintainable code.

Comment: In this case, I'd strongly disagree.

Comment: @slackline: while a list comprehension is indeed a better option for a loop that builds a list by simply appending, your loop is doing a lot more work than is strictly necessary.

Comment: @Sayse: disagree with what, exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can rewrite this as follows:

```
new_list = [y for x in nested_list for d, y in enumerate(x) if d == 1]
```

loops are in the "natural" order, and the condition is in the end. Include `y` only if `d==1`

one possible result (because dicts aren't ordered):

```
[{'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'c': 7, 'd': 8}]
```

Note that in your case, it's simpler and more efficient (`O(n)` vs `O(n**2)`) to write:

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in nested_list]
```

the only difference is that if `x` is too short the latter code will break so maybe test length:

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in nested_list if len(x)>1]
```

Comment: Thanks that's really useful, especially the shorter `x[1]` way of doing it as in my actual use case the nested lists will always be the same length.

Answer (score 5):

> as I'm loosing the counter I get from `enumerate()` when I go from nested loops to list comprehension.

Then why did you drop it? A list comprehension can still use all the same iterators as a `for` loop can.

> I've an if clause in my inner loop and I can't see how to apply this

Just put it in the same place. List comprehensions follow the same nested order for both `for` loops and `if` filters; your loop can be mapped directly by removing the `:` colons, and moving the part in the `.append(...)` call to the front:

```
new_list = [y   # from new_list.append(y)
    for c, x in enumerate(nested_list)   # removed the :
        for d, y in enumerate(x)         # removed the :
            if d == 1]                   # removed the :
```

However, you can drop the first `enumerate()`, because you don't use `c`. You can also drop the second loop and `enumerate()`, because you could use *indexing* instead:

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in nested_list]
```

You don't need to loop over all values in `x` here, that's not a very efficient method to get to that one value.

If your issue is that the `x` list might be *shorter* and not have an element at index 1, filter those nested lists on length first:

```
new_list = [x[1] for x in nested_list if len(x) > 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, having only been using Python for a few months I'm still learning and hadn't realised that you can leave the `if` statements as is. Very clear explanation, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You want the second element for each array in the list, so you can do something like this:

```
new_list = [nested_list[i][1] for i in range(len(nested_list))]
```

better still

```
new_list  = [x[1] for x in nested_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ([ y for c, x in enumerate(nested_list) for d, y in enumerate(x) if d == 1])
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.