# python slicing multi levels list of dict using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have 3 lvls deep list as follows:

```
parent = [
   [
      {'x': 1, 'y': 2},
      {'x': 3, 'y': 8},
      .
      .
      .
   ],
   [
      {'x': 8, 'y': 5},
      {'x': 9, 'y': 6},
      .
      .
      .
   ]
]
```

I am trying to use list comprehension to get all the x into a list and all the y into another list

I tried something like this: 
[gc for gc in [c for c in [p.get('x') for p in parent]]]

but the get('x') is still hitting a list instead of an element, mainly because of the most inner [].  Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: what are these "00" and "01" in your list?

Comment: What is your expected output, a flat or nested list?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18072759/27678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* list comprehensions here.

Here's a functional solution via [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

parent = [[{'x': 1, 'y': 2},
           {'x': 3, 'y': 8}],
          [{'x': 8, 'y': 5},
           {'x': 9, 'y': 6}]]

x, y = zip(*map(itemgetter('x', 'y'), chain.from_iterable(parent)))

print(x)  # (1, 3, 8, 9)
print(y)  # (2, 8, 5, 6)
```

You can, alternatively, use *nested* list comprehensions:

```
x = [i['x'] for L in parent for i in L]
y = [i['y'] for L in parent for i in L]
```

Notice the order of the nested comprehension is consistent with a regular `for` loop:

```
x = []
for L in parent:
    for i in L:
        x.append(i['x'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. x = [i['x'] for L in parent for i in L] is what I needed.   I need to figure out why I struggled with this. ... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehensions you are looking for could be:

```
[ [c.get('x') for c in p] for p in parent]
```

But this should be flattened, so maybe you should do something like:

```
print reduce(
    lambda curr, acc: curr + acc, 
    [ [c.get('x') for c in p] for p in parent],
    []
)
```

Hope this helps.