# BFS list comprehension iterative option

Tags: python, data-structures

This BFS traversal uses a list comprehension to traverse a tree

```
def levelOrderBottom(self, root):
    res, queue = [], [root]
    while queue:
        res.append([node.val for node in queue if node])
        queue = [child for node in queue if node for child in (node.left, node.right)]
    return res[-2::-1]
```

For the

```
  res.append([node.val for node in queue if node])
```

I know that can be done iterative as

```
  for node in queue:
      if node:
          res.append([node.val])
```

but I can't quite wrap my head around what this code

```
  queue = [child for node in queue if node for child in (node.left, node.right)]
```

is doing iteratively, nor replicate it in a non list comprehension format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested list comprehensions translate to nested for loops, in the same order.

```
queue = [child for node in queue if node for child in (node.left, node.right)]
```

becomes

```
queue = []
for node in queue:
    if not node:
        continue
    for child in (node.left, node.right):
        queue.append(child)
```