# Python 3 list comprehension in list of lists to convert types

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

Consider the following list of lists:

`list1 = [['1.1', '1.2', '1.3'], ['2.1', '2.2', '2.3'], ...]`

To comprehend a list of strings to convert them to floats one could use

`list1[0] = [float(i) for i in list1[0]]`

But my attempt to comprehend a list of lists of floats didn't quite work:

```
list1 = [[float(j) for j in list1[i]] for i in list1]
```

due to

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Is there a way to do this sort of list comprehension without using loops explicitly?

Comment: `list1 = [[float(j) for j in > list1[i] <] for i in list1]`

Comment: This is where your error is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Comment: the syntax for i in somelist is actually not giving you the indices 0,1,2,.., instead it gives you the object directly, in your case, the inner list.
so instead of list1[i] you should directly use i

Comment: Using the name `i` for the inner lists is confusing {you confused yourself) because they are lists, but `i` (and `j`) tend    to be used for indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[float(j) for j in i] for i in list1]
```

shall do it

Comment: `i` seems to be a list but I don't know where fortan declared it.

Comment: In python you can directly iterate over items in list. So when you say `for i in list1`, it will iterate over whatever object is stored in `list1` which are lists themselves in this case.