# Converting string to float with error handling inside a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, exception, list-comprehension

Consider the following list of lists:

`list1 = [['1.1','1.2'],['2.1', '2.2'],[''],...]`

This list contains lists with empty strings. To convert all strings in this list of lists to floats one could use list comprehension, such as:

```
[[float(j) for j in i] for i in list1]
```

(thanks [to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56414015/11443913)).

But there is one problem with the lists containing empty strings - they cause an exception:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Is there a way to use this kind of list comprehension without using loops explicitly?

Comment: You will not get an error if the list is actually empty. You're not painting the complete picture here.

Comment: @cs95 You are right, the "empty" lists actually contain empty strings,  I will edit my post.

Comment: So are empty strings to be ignored?

Comment: @Pynchia t's the former if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @cs95 Yes but can this be made into a list comprehension? I understand that empty strings could be removed from the lists beforehand, if that's the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` condition inside the inner list comprehension to ignore empty strings:

```
[[float(j) for j in i if i] for i in list1]
```

`if i` will test the "truthiness" of strings. This will only return False for empty strings, so they are ignored.

Or, if you want to be more robust about it, use a function to perform the conversion with exception handling:

```
def try_convert(val):
    try:
        return float(val)
    except ValueError, TypeError:
        pass

[[float(z) for z in (try_convert(j) for j in i) if z] for i in list1]
```