# Why when we list all the elements of a list for every list in a list of lists we need a specific order in the for in clauses?

Tags: python, list, syntax

I am talking about the order of the `for in` clauses.

This order works:

`[print(element) for element_list in list_of_lists for element in element_list]`

and this doesn't:

`[print(element) for element in element_list for element_list in list_of_lists]`

I personally find the second more readable.

Comment: Why *wouldnt* you need a specific order? If either worked there would be ambiguity. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/3001761 for a visual explanation.

Comment: Yes, the order matters in a list comprehension. It is the same order as the equivalent for-loop, so it is consistent in that regard. Also, **you shouldn't be using a list comprehension here**. List comprehensions aren't for side-effects, like `print`ing. They are for *creating lists*.

Comment: could the compiler work with different orders for list comprehension and for loops?

Answer (score 1):

Reason is quite simple. I guess we agree on lists being an ordered collection, so no issues there. Why the order? It's very simple to remember if you think it like this:

`(elt for subl in lists for elt in subl)`

is the same as

```py
for subl in lists:
    for elt in subl:
        yield elt
```

So, all you need to do to change latter to former is to "unfold" nested for loop by removing colons, already right-indented block then slides to the right and the yield expression is put to the front.

If that is hard to start with, I recommend writing comprehensions so that you first write the loop parts, omit colons and newlines, and put the returned part there last. That is,

1.

```
for subl in lists
    for elt in subl
```

2.

`[for subl in lists for elt in subl]` , note "sliding" to right end

3.

`[elt for subl in lists for elt in subl]`  Finished!

Comment: would it make sense to have different orders in list comprehension than in for loops? I find the incorrect way more readable.

Comment: Understandable, I had it hard at first as well. "Wrong order" feels more natural, but it depends on how you see it; after realizing the rule I explained I find that totally fine.

Also, if you refactor for loops to one-liners or vice versa in vim, there's less work with current syntax ;)