# Reorder array in Python based on a column

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, reorderlist

I have an array like this:

```
a = [[ 8, 7, 6, 5, 9],
     [1, 2, 1, 6, 4],
     [4, 2, 5, 4, 2]]`
```

I want to change the order of that array based on second row with an order like this:
`b = [2, 6, 1, 1, 4]`

So, I want the result becomes like this:

```
a = [[7, 5, 8, 6, 9],
     [2, 6, 1, 1, 4],
     [2, 4, 4, 5, 2]]
```

How can I solve this problem in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[ 8, 7, 6, 5, 9],
    [1, 2, 1, 6, 4],
    [4, 2, 5, 4, 2]]
a[1] = [2, 6, 1, 1, 4]
```

Try that.

Comment: I need to update each row, not only in row number 2.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I'm making the following two assumptions:

- All sub-lists are 5 elements in length
- The desired logic is to move the 2nd and 4th elements to be 1st and 2nd respectively

If both of the assumptions made above are true, you can use [list comprehension on a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list), and create a list to specify how the lists should be reordered.

```
a = [[8, 7, 6, 5, 9],
     [1, 2, 1, 6, 4],
     [4, 2, 5, 4, 2]]

new_ord = [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]

b = [[l[i] for i in new_ord] for l in a]
print(b) #prints: [[7, 5, 8, 6, 9], [2, 6, 1, 1, 4], [2, 4, 4, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Suppose that now I have a different order on b list, could you please help me on how to create a new_order list? since I have an identical value in that list (1).

Comment: @kututaji Not sure what you mean. May need some clarification in the question, or a separate question.