# use list comprehensions to eliminate strings in list that include substrings in another list

Tags: list-comprehension, python-3.7

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = ['https:/zh-cn.fb.com/siml15', 'https:/fb.com/siml29','https:/en-gb.fb.com/siml29','https:/fb.com/siml4529','https:/pt-br.fb.com/siml29']
list_2 = ['zh-cn','en-gb','es-la','fr-fr','ar-ar','pt-br','ko-kr','it-it','de-de','hi-in','ja-jp']
```

I need to remove items in list_1 that includes substrings in list_2

The wanted output:

```
['https:/fb.com/siml29','https:/fb.com/siml4529']
```

Is there a way to use list comprehensions twice?

```
[x for x in list_1 if y for y in list_2 not in x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner comprehension and `all` function for this:

```py
list_1 = ['https:/zh-cn.fb.com/siml15', 'https:/fb.com/siml29', 'https:/en-gb.fb.com/siml29', 'https:/fb.com/siml4529', 'https:/pt-br.fb.com/siml29']
list_2 = ['zh-cn', 'en-gb', 'es-la', 'fr-fr', 'ar-ar', 'pt-br', 'ko-kr', 'it-it', 'de-de', 'hi-in', 'ja-jp']

result = [x for x in list_1 if all(y not in x for y in list_2)]

print(result)
```

```
['https:/fb.com/siml29', 'https:/fb.com/siml4529']
```

Comment: Very clean solution. OP should also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/2554537 answer that shows a gif of how to do nested list comprehensions.