# Find substring in list in a pandas.Series in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe, where one column contains lists. I want to search every list (=every row) and check if one or more elements contain specific substrings.

Data:

```
list_Series = pd.Series([["handful of tomatos", "2 peppers", " tsp salt"],
                        ["1 kg of meat", "fresh basil"]])
```

Search words:

`search_for = ["pepper", "salt"]`

Desired output for 'list_Series':

```
True
False
```

Now I want to apply a (maybe vectorized?) function that checks if a series element contains all the search substrings. If the Series only contains strings and no lists, I would do: `pd.Series.str.contains("salt")`. When looking at a single list I would perform:

```
def filterlist(liste, searchwords):
    occurs = 0
    for word in searchwords:
        for string in liste:
            if word.lower() in string.lower():
                occurs += 1
                break 
        if occurs == len(searchwords):                   
            return True
```

But this is very clunky and long. And I guess not very efficient when applying to a whole pd.Series. And I don't know how to apply it to a Series.

Thanks for the help! Also looking for feedback, this is my first post on stackoverflow!
Also would it be better to convert this series into a dataframe?

Comment: You can't vectorize this. In fact, plenty of the `.str` methods run slower than list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nested list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18072759/8565438):

```
result = [listelement for searchtarget in search_for for each_list_in_series in list_Series for listelement in each_list_in_series if searchtarget in listelement]
```

`result` will be:

```
['2 peppers', ' tsp salt']
```

This is equivalent to, without list comprehensions:

```
result=[]
for searchtarget in search_for:
    for each_list_in_series in list_Series:
        for listelement in each_list_in_series:
            if searchtarget in listelement:
                result.append(listelement)
```

A nice visual aide for nested list comprehensions, from [Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5452365/rahul)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/8565438) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list):

[image]

Comment: That comprehension just crashes my brain. The overuse of `each` is borderline unintelligible

Comment: I am looking for your better alternative :)

Comment: Better names at the very least? It's horrible to look at for now; I can't even process it properly

Comment: Better names done, now working on an explanation, few mins...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and posting the equivalent! That is a lot easier to understand!

Comment: Edited the answer; I hope both of you like it better now :)