# List comprehension combine 2 elements in nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension, nested-lists

Is it possible to use list comprehension to combine 2 elements in a nested list based on the occurrence of a character, eg: if you encounter '+' combine with the next element? I have some code that does this using nested loops, but trying to achieve using list comprehension.

Input:
`l = [['A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', '+', '100', 'A-5'],['B-2', 'B-3', 'B-4', '+', '500', 'B-5']]`

Output:
`l = [['A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', '+100', 'A-5'],['B-2', 'B-3', 'B-4', '+500', 'B-5']]`

Code:

```
for nested in l: 
   z = iter(nested)
   for i in z:
      if i == '+':
         i = i+next(z)
```

Comment: No '+', '100' becomes '+100'

Comment: Got it. Sorry for that.

Comment: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list) for nested list comprehension

Comment: @will.cass.wrig but far from duplicate. This is more complex, combining some elements and leaving some as is.

Comment: @schwobaseggl agreed, just wanted to include it as a reference for other variations on the solution. your solution is good, that's why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 5):

The following will work:

```
[[x + next(i) if x == "+" else x for x in i] for i in map(iter, l)]

# [['A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', '+100', 'A-5'], ['B-2', 'B-3', 'B-4', '+500', 'B-5']]
```

If the last element might be a `"+"`, you could pass a default value to `next`

```
next(i, "")
```

to avoid an error.

Comment: The OP probably doesn't need it, but you could do `next(i, '')` in case the last element is an "+".