# Modify nested list elements using list comprehension

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I wanted to produce `lst_new` such that,

```
items = (.1, .5, .9)
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

lst_new == [[[.1, 2, 3], [.4, 5, 6], [.7, 8, 9]], [[.5, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [3.5, 8, 9]], [[.9, 2, 3], [3.6, 5, 6], [6.3, 8, 9]]]
```

Using list comprehension,

```
lst_new = [x[0] * i for i in items for x in lst]
```

But obviously it doesn't work as intended. Help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/5452365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only including the first value of `x`, not all of them, and you need a nested list comprehension to add depth to the list structure:

```py
lst_new = [[[x[0] * m] + x[1:] for x in lst] for m in items]
```

Output

```
[
 [[0.1, 2, 3], [0.4, 5, 6], [0.7, 8, 9]],
 [[0.5, 2, 3], [2.0, 5, 6], [3.5, 8, 9]],
 [[0.9, 2, 3], [3.6, 5, 6], [6.3, 8, 9]]
]
```