# simpler way for getting data from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary:
The last entry of a tuple are the minutes when the goals were shot.
For example: Oscar a Brazilian player shot a goal in the 90th minute

```
players = {
    "Brazil": [
        (12, "Júlio César", "Goalkeeper", []),
        (4, "David Luiz", "Defender", []),
        (6, "Marcelo", "Defender", []),
        (13, "Dante", "Defender", []),
        (23, "Maicon", "Defender", []),
        (5, "Fernandinho", "Midfielder", []),
        (7, "Hulk", "Midfielder", []),
        (8, "Paulinho", "Midfielder", []),
        (11, "Oscar", "Midfielder", [90]),
        (16, "Ramires", "Midfielder", []),
        (17, "Luiz Gustavo", "Midfielder", []),
        (19, "Willian", "Midfielder", []),
        (9, "Fred", "Striker", []),
    ],
    "Germany": [
        (1, "Manuel Neuer", "Goalkeeper", []),
        (4, "Benedikt Höwedes", "Defender", []),
        (5, "Mats Hummels", "Defender", []),
        (16, "Philipp Lahm", "Defender", []),
        (17, "Per Mertesacker", "Defender", []),
        (20, "Jérôme Boateng", "Defender", []),
        (6, "Sami Khedira", "Midfielder", [29]),
        (7, "Bastian Schweinsteiger", "Midfielder", []),
        (8, "Mesut Özil", "Midfielder", []),
        (13, "Thomas Müller", "Midfielder", [11]),
        (14, "Julian Draxler", "Midfielder", []),
        (18, "Toni Kroos", "Midfielder", [24, 26]),
        (9, "André Schürrle", "Striker", [69, 79]),
        (11, "Miroslav Klose", "Striker", [23]),
    ],
}
```

I want to create a function that takes the team and a minute as input and returns the number of goals that were shot to that minute.
I tried it like this:

```
def score_at_minute(team,minute):
    global players
    goals = [goals for (number, player, position, goals) in players[team] if len(goals)>=1]
    goals_1 = [goal[0] for goal in goals if len(goal)>=1 if goal[0] <= minute]
    goals_2 = [goal[1] for goal in goals if len(goal) ==2 if goal[1]<= minute]
    all_goals = goals_1+goals_2
    return len(all_goals)
```

My function call looks like this:

```
score_at_minute("Germany",90)
```

Is there a simpler way or in the best way a one liner?

Comment: `(12, "Júlio César", "Goalkeeper", [])` what are these, please describe

Comment: This is described by the OP as: `(number, player, position, goals)`

Comment: the goals are the minutes when they were shot. I edited my post

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please give a [mre] to illustrate the specific problem.

Comment: Yes this code works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this -

```
def score_at_minute(x,y):
    return len([j for i in players.get(x) for j in i[3] if j<=y])

score_at_minute("Germany",25)
```

```
3
```

Another version -

```
score_at_minute = lambda x,y: len([j for i in players.get(x) for j in i[3] if j<=y])

score_at_minute('Germany', 90)
```

```
7
```

---

How this works -

1. `players.get(x)` fetches the list of players and goals under the country x
2. `i[3]` is the item that holds the list of goals
3. When iterating over this, you will end up with a list of lists, where each sublist contains goals. `[[],[],[],[24],[32,45]]` .. etc.
4. You can now flatten the list of lists by using `[item for sublist in list for item in sublist]`
5. Then you can apply the filter over this list (less than equal to the input minutes)
6. Finally calculate the length.

Comment: thank you. I tried it with an double list comprehension but this did not work for me. Could you explain it?

Comment: what do you mean? doesnt this work for you? because this is a single list comprehension

Comment: Ill add an explanation.

Comment: yes it works but there are two for statements in the comprehension but now I understand it

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use list comprehension

```py
# For Germany
# For less than 90 minutes
len([eg for _,_,_,g in players['Germany'] for eg in g if eg<90])
```

```
7
```

Answer (score 0):

using `items()`

```
def score_at_minute(team,minute):        
    for key,val in players.items():
        if key==team:            
            return(len([j for i in val  for j in i[3] if j <=minute]))
```