# List comprehension behavior with 2 for loop

Tags: python

Here is the code to emulate python zip function.

```
def myzip(*args):
    return [tuple(a[i] for a in args) for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))]

print(myzip([10, 20,30], 'abc'))   

#output: [(10, 'a'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c')]
```

If I remove the tuple(), the output will be: [10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']

I don't quite understand how list comprehension works when we just add tuple()

So after each 2 loop, it yield a value and automatically add it to internal list before turning into tuple and finally add them to outer list?

For eg:

Loop 1: 10
Loop 2: a
Add to [10,a] -> tuple([10,a]) -> (10,a)

Loop 2: 20
Loop 2: b
Add to [20,b] -> tuple([20,b]) -> (20,b)

....

Comment: It is a good question. I don't think your explanation in e.g is right. It seems that python goes on the whole 2 full loops, and somehow keeps the values in memory. And after the two loops, add in the same tuple, the values of different args but with same index

Comment: *"List comprehension with 2 for loops"* is called ***nested list comprehension***

Comment: ...and when you say *"remove the tuple()"*, you mean *"but keep the nested list comprehension"*, so: `[a[i] for a in args for i in range(...)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just has to do with where you position the different parts of the list comprehension expression.

With the `tuple()` call in place, you are calling the `tuple` function and passing the generator `(a[i] for a in args)`. So, automatically, the portion `for a in args` will be considered the inner loop. Hence, `[(10, 'a'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c')]`.

This can be expanded to:

```py
>>> ret = []
>>> for i in range(len(min(args, key=len))):
        sub = []
        for a in args:
            sub.append(a[i])
        ret.append(tuple(sub))

    
>>> ret
[(10, 'a'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c')]
```

Without the `tuple()` call in place, the portion `for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))` becomes the inner loop. Hence, `[10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']`.

This can be expanded to:

```py
>>> ret = []
>>> for a in args:
        for i in range(len(min(args, key=len))):
            ret.append(a[i])

        
>>> ret
[10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you were two switch the two loops to make this:

```py
[a[i] for i in range(len(min(args, key=len))) for a in args]
```

Now, the portion `for a in args` is back to the inner loop. Hence, `[10, 'a', 20, 'b', 30, 'c']`.

This can be expanded to:

```py
>>> ret = []
>>> for i in range(len(min(args, key=len))):
        for a in args:
            ret.append(a[i])

        
>>> ret
[10, 'a', 20, 'b', 30, 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Now I see the how the order of for loop impacts the final result. But in your expanded example, we still need 2 list to handle. With list comprehension, how exactly it handle each value? Because tuple is immutable, we can not just add "10", then add "a" to it I guess.

Comment: The `tuple()` function doesn't create an empty tuple and add values to it. Rather, it takes an iterable (list, string, etc.) and returns a tuple of those values. In this case, the iterable is a generator (any list comprehension expression in parentheses instead of brakets is a generator) and `tuple()` returns a tuple of the values which are yielded from that generator.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove `tuple` you are no longer making the individual sub lists (or tuples) and you have changed the inner vs outer loops in the comprehension.

This comprehension works (in a similar fashion to `tuple(a[i] for a in args)`):

```
[[a[i] for a in args] for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))]
# [[10, 'a'], [20, 'b'], [30, 'c']] with myzip([10,20,30],'abc')
```

since the `[a[i] for a in args]` is executed entirely *before* the next `i`; ie, each `i`'th index in each `a` is added to a sub list in turn and a sublist of those results is added to the resulting list. Hence `[a[i] for a in args]` is the inner loop and `for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))` is the outer loop.

But this:

```
 [a[i] for a in args for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))]
 # [10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c'] with myzip([10,20,30],'abc')
```

exhausts the `i` list before going to the next `a` in args. The `i` list is then restarted and explains why you get `[10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']` instead of `[(10, 'a'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c')]` Removing either `[]` or `tuple()` has now made `for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))` the inner loop and `a[i] for a in args` has now become the outer loop.

---

And this:

```
[(a[i] for a in args) for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))]
```

creates a list of generators.

Answer (score 3):

> If I remove the tuple(), the output will be: [10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']

I assume you meant

```
>>> def myzip(*args):
...     return [a[i] for a in args for i in range(len(min(args, key=len)))]
...
>>> print(myzip([10, 20,30], 'abc'))
[10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

which is equivalent to

```
>>> def myzip(*args):
...     results = []
...     for a in args:
...         for i in range(len(min(args, key=len))):
...             results.append(a[i])
...     return results
...
>>> print(myzip([10, 20,30], 'abc'))
[10, 20, 30, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

This essentially flattens the nested list in `args`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/5399734) on more about "nested" list comprehension.