# Simplify array processing and enumerate to a one-liner

Tags: python, arrays, simplify, one-liner

How can I simplify the following:

```
imgs = []
for i, obj in enumerate(objlist):
    imgs.append(  foo(obj, f"img-{i}.png")  )
```

where `objlist` an array of objects
and `foo` is a method that processes the object and saves an image receiving both the object and the new file name, it returns the same name given.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple transformation into a list comprehension:

```py
imgs = [foo(obj, f"img-{i}.png") for (i, obj) in enumerate(objlist)]
```

(btw you forgot the `in` in your `for` loop.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) answer on the general problem of converting nested for loops into a single list comprehension.

Comment: yeah i lost the "in" during code anonimation process