# List comprehension of lists inside a list of objects

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have the following data structure:

```
SOME_LIST = [
  {
    'name': 'foo',
    'alternatives': [
      {
        'name': 'Foo'
      },
      {
        'name': 'foo'
      },
      {
        'name': 'fu
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'bar',
    'alternatives': [
      {
        'name': 'Bar'
      },
      {
        'name': 'bar'
      },
      {
        'name': 'ba'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to produce a flattened list of the alternative "names" of the object as follows:

```
['foo', 'Foo', 'fu', ..., 'ba']
```

I've gone around the houses with various list comprehensions...and I just don't know how to do this elegantly.

I've tried:

```
[i['alternatives'] for i in SOME_LIST]

[*i['alternatives'] for i in SOME_LIST]
>>>SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension

[alt['name'] for alt in [i['alternatives'] for i in SOME_LIST]]
>>>TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Please update your question with some of the `around the houses` code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana Duly noted, and updated.

Comment: Your starting data structure is pretty bizarre. But [shrug] sometimes that's what you get to work with. It's a little unclear whether you want the original `SOME_LIST[i]['name']` included in the final list too, although in this case those also appear in the `'alternatives'` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
result = [j['name'] for i in SOME_LIST for j in i['alternatives']]
```

Output:

```
['Foo', 'foo', 'fu', 'Bar', 'bar', 'ba']
```

Comment: Gahhh, frustrating but boom!

Comment: Also see this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) on converting a nested for loop to a nested list comprehension.