# Change for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So my input file `f` is like

```
5 100
2 200
8 300
```

My output is a list of tuples:

```
[(5, 100), (2, 200), (8, 300)]
```

My code is as below.

```
f = open(file_name, "r")
lines = f.readlines()

sets= []
for line in lines:
    a, b= line.split(' ')
    sets.append((int(a), int(b)))
```

Is it possible to convert the for loop to a list comprehension? Also someone told me a list comprehension is faster to run in most cases. Is it the case? And is it always a good practice to convert iterative operations to a shorter list comprehension when possible?

Comment: You need to see this [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    sets = [tuple(map(int, line.split(" "))) for line in f]
```

---

Regarding your other questions: comprehensions are often faster, yes, but not always significantly so, and it's hard to comment in the abstract without a concrete use case.

Your second question is more opinionated, and again, varies with each use case. For relatively simple operations like this one, I find a list comprehension to be more readable and to-the-point than a for-loop (though I tend to try to avoid nested comprehensions where possible — notice I used `map` rather than a nested-comprehension in my answer — it's just personal preference, really). Moreover, not everything that can be written as a for-loop can be rewritten as a comprehension, and not everything that *can* be written as a comprehension necessarily *should* be written as a comprehension. For more complex operations, it can often make it really unreadable to cram it into one comprehension, so in those cases you're almost certainly better off sticking with a for-loop.

Comment: Huh, I see it iterates over the lines without calling readlines(). Will edit my answer, thanks @Matthias

Answer (score 3):

```
sets = [tuple(int(val) for val in line.split(" ")) for line in lines]
```