# Using list comprehension and extend

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this

```
rows = self.rows()
aaa = []
for r in range(0, 9, 3):
    bbb = []
    for c in range(0, 9, 3):
        ccc = []
        for s in range(3):
            ccc.extend(rows[r+s][c:c+3])
        bbb.append(ccc)
    aaa.append(bbb)
```

and it returns this

```
[
    [
        [5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2, 9],
        [3, 8, 0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4]
    ],
    [
        [0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 3, 1],
        [0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 3, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 6]
    ]
]
```

which is correct.
`rows` is just a list containing 9 other nested lists, each with exactly 9 integers ranging 0 through 9.

When I try to use list comprehension

```
[[rows[r+s][c:c+3] for s in range(3) for c in range(0, 9, 3)] for r in range(0, 9, 3)]
```

I get this

```
[
    [
        [5, 0, 0],
        [3, 8, 0],
        [0, 6, 2],
        [0, 6, 0],
        [4, 9, 2],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 9],
        [0, 0, 6],
        [3, 0, 4]
    ],
    [
        [0, 7, 6],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 3, 1],
        [0, 0, 8],
        [2, 0, 5],
        [0, 4, 9],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 3, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [4, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 3],
        [6, 0, 3],
        [7, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 8],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 6]
    ]
]
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what? I've checked other SO questions and they allude to structuring the LC a certain way to stop the innermost list splitting into 9 separate lists, but so far, it's not happening.

Comment: I always find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) helpful when converting a nested for loop to a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana, that will come in useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want.  This version uses bare Python with no libraries, but seems to be the most concise (of the solutions that work):

```
[[[rows[r+s][c+i] for s in range(3) for i in range(3)] for c in range(0, 9, 3)] for r in range(0, 9, 3)]
```

Formatted more readably, this is just:

```
[[[rows[r+s][c+i] for s in range(3)
                  for i in range(3)]
  for c in range(0, 9, 3)]
 for r in range(0, 9, 3)]
```

This replaces the slice in the original loop nest with an inner `i` loop, eliminating the need to concatenate intermediate slices (or to generate them).

Comment: Thank you! I can see where I was going wrong now, appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import itertools

[[list(itertools.chain(*[rows[r+s][c:c+3] for s in range(3)])) for c in range(0, 9, 3)] for r in range(0, 9, 3)]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Guess now is as good a time as any to start using itertools.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
print([[rows[r+s][c:c+3] * 3 for c in range(0, 9, 3)] for r in range(0, 9, 3)])
```

Comment: Gives me `NameError: name 's' is not defined`, I believe because you replaced `s in range(3)` with *3.