# How make for loop from comprehensive for loop

Tags: python

As a learner of python, I am confused about some functions. Someone, please make a normal loop from this comprehensive loop. Here **items** is a dictionary.

```
items={1:'a',2:'b',4:'d',5:'e'}

items = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(items.values(), start=1)}
```

I want to make a normal for loop of the upper comprehensive loop. I have tried but don't get the exact result. Look here:

```
for k,v in enumerate(items.values(),start =1):
                  `items ={k:v}`
```

Help me.

Comment: Did you mean `items.items()` instead of `items.values()`?

Comment: Also, you aren't building up a new dict; you are just repeatedly replacing the previous value of `items` with a new one.

Comment: This [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) shows the reverse process. It might still be useful here.

Comment: Yes chepner I understand what was wrong I am doing. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write directly back into `items` with for loop. The list comprehension works because it creates a new dictionary and replaces the old one. While for-loop can't do that by itself. So you need to create a new dictionary and add key-values to it:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in enumerate(items.values(), start=1):
    new_dict[k] = v
```

if needed replace old one with new one afterwards:

```
items = new_dict
```