# Python - stuck with correct list assignment

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Here's the thing:

```
coords = [['60', '01'], ['30', '19']]
coords = [int(coords[i][j])/60**j for i in range(2) for j in range(len(coords[i]))]
```

Expected output:

```
>>>[[60.0, 0.016666666666666666], [30.0, 0.31666666666666665]]
```

What i've got:

```
>>>[60.0, 0.016666666666666666, 30.0, 0.31666666666666665]
```

Gimme a hint: how to assign values through list comprehension in a desired way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the order of the `for` loops and add brackets:

```
coords = [[int(coords[i][j])/60**j for j in range(len(coords[i]))] for i in range(2)]
print(coords)
```

Output:

```
[[60.0, 0.016666666666666666], [30.0, 0.31666666666666665]]
```

Comment: What a coincidence!

Answer (score 2):

Since you've hard-coded the value 2 as the length of the inner arrays, you could use a simpler comprehension:

```
coords = [[int(a), int(b)/60] for a,b in coords ]
```

Comment: Yep! Indeed it's probably more correct to model these as tuples, since it appears to be an ordered pair. `data = [('60', '01'), ('30', '19')]; coords = [(int(a), int(b)/60) for a,b in coords]`

Comment: @AdamSmith - I agree. The only reason that these are lists is to match the output requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the second for loop and enclose it in brackets:

```
coords = [[int(coords[i][j])/60**j for j in range(len(coords[i]))] for i in range(2) ]
```

Output:

```
[[60.0, 0.016666666666666666], [30.0, 0.31666666666666665]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
[[int(j)/60**idx for idx, j in enumerate(i)] for i in coords]
```

```
[[60.0, 0.016666666666666666], [30.0, 0.31666666666666665]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[
 [int(element)/60**i for i, element in enumerate(sublist)]
     for sublist in coords
]
```