# Two for loops in list comprehension produce weird output in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I've written this code:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

print([x**2 for x in l1 for y in l2])
```

which outputs this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

My question is, what is happening inside this list comprehension? Why is the amount of items in `l1` multiplied by the length of `l2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Comment: What are you expecting two `for` clauses to do?

Comment: Because the comprehension goes through l1 for each element of l2, i.e. l2 times, so a total of l2*l1 results.

Comment: If this strikes you as "weird" -- what was the non-weird result that you were expecting?

Comment: Note that the second list is useless, only its length matters. You would get the same with `print([x**2 for x in l1 for _ in range(4)])`

Comment: Guys, I came across this code by accident, I'm not trying to achieve anything with it, I just wanted to see what's happening here. Hopefully got the answer already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like you do:

```py
for x in l1:
   for y in l2: #this loop has len(l2) iteration
      print(x**2)
```

In the `y` loop, you only use variable `x`, which doesn't change for `len(l2)` iterations.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening here.

First: `print([x**2 for x in l1...`

This is taking each of the elements in l1 and squaring them producing `[1, 4, 9, 16]`

Second: `... for y in l2])`

This is repeating this process (squaring and printing the element in l1) one time for each value in l2 which is why you are getting 4 of each squared value.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension is equivalent to the following `for` loops:

```
result = []
for y in l2:
    for x in l1:
        result.append(x**2)
```

From this you can see why the inner loop is repeating 4 times.

If you want to loop over the two lists in parallel, not nested, use `zip()`:

```
[x**2 for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: I guess the order of for loops is swapped. It doesn't produce the same result as my comprehension :)