# Multiplying 2D list by 1D list to each elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to multiply a one dimensional list with a two dimensional list's elements. How can I do it with list comprehension?

```
a = [1,2]
b = [[3,4],[5,6]]
```

The desired result is

```
c = [[3,8],[5,12]
```

I have tried this way

```
c = [i*j for i, j in zip(a,b)]
```

The error that I encountered was

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension:

```
c = [ [x * y for x, y in zip(a, row)] for row in b ]
```