# Understanding python syntax

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables

I am in the process of learning Python. I came across a review question and am having some trouble understanding the notation of how a variable is declared. Below is the variable:

```
t = [[3-i for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

I am familiar with the range function but am unsure with the above notation. My assumption of what is happening is the variable `t` has a nested for loop. I am more familiar with the following notation:

```
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
      # some code
```

but I am unsure how the first part of the variable `3-i` plays a factor in this. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: your assumption is correct , and its called  `list comprehension`

Comment: How about you run the code and observe the results? The result would give you a better understanding!

Comment: You have your nested for loops in reverse. It's creating a list of `3-i` for each `i`, and then repeating that list for each `j`. Also, if it helps, you can think of `3-i` as `(3-i)` which is basically just the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list) (particularly, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611767/2745495 which describes the equivalent for-loops)

Comment: See also https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/