# how to convert nested for loops into list comprehension in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, flatten, nested-for-loop

I was working on flattening this multidimensional list

```
f_list =[[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6]], 
[[7, 8, 9]]]
```

and i did using nested for loops  like so

```
new_l=[]
for sublist in f_list:
    for subsublist in sublist:
        for i in subsublist:
            new_l.append(i)
print(new_l)
```

but i want to convert it using list comprehension but i am confused on how to go about it. i've read some documentation where it said to take the last bit of the loop to start off and go from top to bottom but, it did not work

```
new_l =[i for subsublist in f_list for sublist in subsublist for  sublist in f_list]
```

and tried this as well

```
new_l =[i for subsublist in sublist for subsublist in sublist for  sublist in f_list]
```

i am very confused

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension on a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go one step at a time:

Step 1:

```py
new_l=[]
for sublist in f_list:
    for subsublist in sublist:
        [new_l.append(i) for i in subsublist]
```

Step 2:

```py
new_l=[]
for sublist in f_list:
    [new_l.append(i) for subsublist in sublist for i in subsublist]
```

Step 3:

```py
new_l = []
[new_l.append(i) for sublist in f_list for subsublist in sublist for i in subsublist]
```

And finally:

```py
new_l = [i for sublist in f_list for subsublist in sublist for i in subsublist]
```

---

You might want to take a look at [Flattening an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/)

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to go from top to bottom while converting nested loops to list comprehension.

```py
f_list =[[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]]]

new_l = [i for sublist in f_list for subsublist in sublist for i in subsublist]

print(new_l)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution:

```
[i for sublist in f_list for subsublist in sublist   for i in subsublist ]
```

Comment: check your answer once

Comment: I checked, try to see if you set correctly