# Converting "for" loop with nested "for" loop and "If" statement into List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I convert the following code into a list comprehension?

```
for i in range(xy-1):
    for b in range(i+1, xy):
        if(fuzz.token_set_ratio(Names[i], Names[b]) >= 90):
            FuzzNames[b].append(ID[i])
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I always refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) when converting back and forth.

Comment: This is made a little more tricky because it doesn't return a single list.  It's filling in some values, and leaving other values alone.

Comment: I don't think this can be a list comprehension. It's not creating new lists, it's appending to existing lists. And it's appending to a different list each time through the loop. I thought it could be done by swapping the order of the `for` loops, but `b` is dependent on `i`.

Comment: I am doing a fuzzy search between 32,000 lines of data, the code took 7 hours but did not finish.

I read about how to make my code faster, one of the solutions was list comprehension.
This is the main block in my code, so I wondered how to do it

Comment: The list processing is NOT your bottleneck.  Have you timed the individual fuzzy searches?  If a single search takes 1 second, then 32,000 searches will take 9 hours.

Comment: I did time the fuzzy search of 100, 200, 400 and 800 search to do some approximation. It will take me more than 9 hours.


I did some changes to my code, but the last one was the list processing

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
indices = [(i,b) for i in range(xy-1) for b in range(i+1, xy) if fuzz.token_set_ratio(Names[i], Names[b]) >= 90]

for i, b in indices:
  FuzzNames[b].append(ID[i])
```

However, the way you originally wrote it is more readable and easier to understand, and it's not likely that you need that list of indices later on.

Comment: This is a little faster. The data I am working with have 11 columns, every one with ten of thousands of line.

This will save hours for me, thank you.