# Get new list from substrings between two lists with list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

Having the following 2 lists

```
a =["my car","your car","his car","her car","their car","her bike","your house","his job"]
b = ["your","her"]
```

I'm trying to get the elements from `list a` that contains the string of elements in `list b` in the same order of appeareance, so the expected output would be like

```
out = ["your car","her car","her bike","your house"]
```

My attempt with nested for loop that works is this

```
out = []
for z in a:
    for w in b:
        if w in z:
            out.append(z)
```

I'm stuck in trying to convert to list comprehension. I've tried suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/list-comprehension-on-a-nested-list) question in the way below but I'm getting wrong answer. Thanks for any help

```
>>> [[z for z in a] for w in z if w in z]
[['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job'], 
 ['my car', 'your car', 'his car', 'her car', 'their car', 'her bike', 'your house', 'his job']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ELEMENT for x in a for y in b if y in x]
```

*ELEMENT*: whatever expression you define which is generated for every iteration to its right, if the trailing condition is satisfied

```
>>> a =["my car","your car","his car","her car","their car","her bike","your house","his job"]
>>> b = ["your","her"]
>>> [x for x in a for y in b if y in x]
['your car', 'her car', 'her bike', 'your house']
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw my error now with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given the solution you say that DOES work:

```py
out = []
for z in a:
    for w in b:
        if w in z:
            out.append(z)
```

Converting this to list comprehension is basically just like reading down the stack

```py
out = [z for z in a for w in b if w in z]
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw my error now with your solution.