# How to flatten list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am learning how to traverse lists and dictionaries in Python. I am a beginner.

```
process = [
                {
                'process1':
                            [
                                {"subprocess1":["subprocess1_1","subprocess1_2"]},
                                "subprocess2",
                                {"subprocess3":["subprocess3_1", "subprocess3_2"]},
                                "subprocess4",
                                {"subprocess5":[{"subprocess5_1":["subprocess5_1_1","subprocess5_1_2"]}]},
                            ],
                    },
                {
                'process2':
                            [
                                "subprocess2_1"
                            ]
                }
      ]
```

How do I flatten above list of dictionaries into the following?

```
process1 = [subprocess1, subprocess1_1, subprocess1_2, subprocess2, subprocess3, subprocess3_1, subprocess3_2, subprocess4, subprocess5, subprocess5_1, subprocess5_1_1, subprocess5_1_2]
process2 = [subprocess2_1]
```

Comment: Figure out first how to iterate over a simple flat list (item by item) and a simple flat dictionary (key-value pairs). Once you know that, a nested list of dicts with lists is essentially the same: loop over the outer list, then each item would be a dict, so loop over the keys and values of the dict, then each value of the dict would be a list, so on and on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, it's always useful to use a recursive function/generator:

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for item in x:
            yield from flatten(item)
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        for k, v in x.items():
            yield k
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield x
        
out = {k: list(flatten(v)) for d in process for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
out['process1']
# ['subprocess1', 'subprocess1_1', 'subprocess1_2', 'subprocess2',
#  'subprocess3', 'subprocess3_1', 'subprocess3_2', 'subprocess4',
#  'subprocess5', 'subprocess5_1', 'subprocess5_1_1', 'subprocess5_1_2']

out['process2']
# ['subprocess2_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nested for-loops](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-loops/) or [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) are common ways to [flatten objects of **fixed** depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079294/6146136); and [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion) is generally useful for flattening objects of **arbitrary** depth, so you can

- flatten by one more level with each recursive call, and
- use [`isinstance`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance) to detect dictionaries before getting [`.values`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/values), and
- use [`hasattr`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hasattr) to check if an input has `__iter__` (and is, therefore, [iterable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-iterable-in-python/))

You can use the nested loop in a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator) function

```py
def flatten_obj(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, str): 
        for i in (obj.values() if isinstance(obj, dict) else obj):
            for v in flatten_obj(i): yield v
    else: yield obj
```

But if you want the function to return a list, list comprehension might be preferable to initiating an empty list and appending to it in a nested loop.

```py
def get_flat_list(obj, listify_single=False):
    if isinstance(obj, str) or not hasattr(obj, '__iter__'): 
        return [obj] if listify_single else obj
    
    if isinstance(obj, dict): obj = obj.values()
    return [v for x in obj for v in get_flat_list(x,listify_single=True)]
```

---

Using

- either <kbd>**`{k: list(flatten_obj(v)) for i in process for k,v in i.items()}`**</kbd>
- or <kbd>**`{k: get_flat_list(v) for i in process for k,v in i.items()}`**</kbd>

should return

> ```py
> {
>   'process1': ['subprocess1_1', 'subprocess1_2', 'subprocess2', 'subprocess3_1', 'subprocess3_2', 'subprocess4', 'subprocess5_1_1', 'subprocess5_1_2'],
>   'process2': ['subprocess2_1']
> }
> ```

Ofc you can also define `process1` and `process2` as separate variables:

```py
process1 = get_flat_list(process[0]['process1']) 
# list(flatten_obj(process[0]['process1']))

process2 = get_flat_list(process[1]['process2']) 
# list(flatten_obj(process[1]['process2']))
```

or

```py
process1, process2, *_ = [list(flatten_obj(v)) for i in process for v in i.values()]
# process1, process2, *_ = [get_flat_list(v) for i in process for v in i.values()]
```

Comment: Love the fixed depth vs arbitrary depth point - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another aproach which uses the flatten function which takes a nested list or dictionary as input and returns a flattened list of its elements. It uses recursion to handle nested lists and dictionaries of arbitrary depth.

To use the function with your process data structure, you can extract the nested lists from the dictionary values using indexing and pass them to the flatten function. Here's how you can do it:

```
# define the flatten function
def flatten(lst):
    # create an empty list to store the flattened list
    result = []
    # iterate through each element in the input list
    for item in lst:
        # if the element is a dictionary, recursively flatten its values
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for val in item.values():
                result.extend(flatten(val))
        # if the element is a list, recursively flatten its elements
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            result.extend(flatten(item))
        # otherwise, append the element to the result list
        else:
            result.append(item)
    # return the flattened list
    return result

# extract the nested lists and flatten them
process1 = flatten(process[0]['process1'])
process2 = flatten(process[1]['process2'])

print(process1)
print(process2)
```

This will output:

```
['subprocess1_1', 'subprocess1_2', 'subprocess2', 'subprocess3_1', 'subprocess3_2', 'subprocess4', 'subprocess5_1_1', 'subprocess5_1_2']
['subprocess2_1']
```