# Generator expression not working as intended when used in a pipeline

Tags: python

I am experimenting working with generator expressions in order to understand them better.
I have a text file that I was expecting the following code to print each word in each line of the file separately:

```
lines = open("file.txt")
split_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
words = (word for word in split_lines)
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

One way I found to fix it in order to do what I intended was to discard the words generator expression and just do a nested loop to walk through the created list:

```
lines = open("file.txt")
split_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
for split_line in split_lines:
    for word in split_line:
        print(word)
```

But I am still wondering what is the gap in my understanding that I don't see why the first option wouldn't work (it seems like the words generator expression effectively does nothing and just leaves me with the same list I had the line prior).

Comment: Your comment in brackets at the end is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759/how-can-i-use-list-comprehensions-to-process-a-nested-list/45079294#45079294) to another question give you any insights?

Comment: `(x for x in whatever)` is pretty much equivalent to just `whatever`

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga yea I suppose so, but this insight is not so trivial at first sight. 
I thought that pipelining the way I did (generator expression put into variable 1, then another one which is based on variable 1 put into variable 2, and so on), allowed me to go deeper into sub-elements, but as I saw from Tom Karzes and pwoolvett's answers below, the way to achieve that is actually the nested "for ... in ... for ... in ...", otherwise I can't go from elements deeper into sub-elements with mere pipelining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with generators. Eg if you replace the `(` for `[` to create lists:

```
>>> split_lines = [line.split() for line in open('file.txt')]
>>> words = [word for word in split_lines]
>>> words
[['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:45:57', '-03', '2024'], ['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:46:00', '-03', '2024'], ['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:46:01', '-03', '2024'], ['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:46:02', '-03', '2024'], ['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:46:02', '-03', '2024'], ['Thu', 'Mar', '14', '16:46:02', '-03', '2024']]
```

You can see the problem is your second expression is just iterating over the first one and yielding the same thing it receives.

In this case, you want to iterate over the elements within, not the elements themselves, which could be achieved with `words = (word for line in split_lines for word in line)` (or using a `list`, the idea is the same)

Answer (score 2):

The `split_line` generator will yield the result of each `line.split()` expression.  Those are lists of words, not words.  For example:

```
lines = ["a b c", "d e f"]
>>> split_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
>>> list(split_lines)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>>
```

To flatten those lists, so that your `words` generator yields individual words rather than lists of words, you can do:

```
>>> split_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
>>> words = (word for line in split_lines for word in line)
>>> list(words)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>>
```

So your original example would look like:

```
lines = open("file.txt")
split_lines = (line.split() for line in lines)
words = (word for line in split_lines for word in line)
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

You could also combine the generators, eliminating the need for  `split_lines`:

```
lines = open("file.txt")
words = (word for line in lines for word in line.split())
for word in words:
    print(word)
```