# How to flatmap list of lists of lists of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am using Calendar and recieve list of lists of lists of tuples from it

```
calendar.Calendar.yeardays2calendar(calendar.Calendar(), year, 1))
```

Output is:

```
[[[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6)], [(5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 6)], [(12, 0), (13, 1),...
```

I want to flat map it to simple tuples list saving their order. What is the best way to do map list of any deepness into plain list in python 2.7?

Example of what I want:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6),(5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 0), (13, 1)...
```

Tryied code from other questions - didn't help. Sorry for silly questions, I'm new to python

UPD I tried functions from here [python list comprehensions; compressing a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists) - didn't help

Comment: What was the other code you tried , and what was the issue with that  ?

Comment: I didn't get errors, but it couldn't flatten my list, because all examples were for list of lists like [[1,3,4],[4,3],[3]] which is not my case

Comment: You should post what you tried in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a function to flatten one nesting level.  It goes by the unfortunate name `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`.  If you apply it three times, it will flatten three levels:

```
import itertools
flatten1 = itertools.chain.from_iterable
flattened_data = flatten1(flatten1(flatten1(your_data)))
for a, b in flattened_data:
    # whatever
```

More generically, a function that flattens `n` levels would be

```
def flatten_n(n, iterable):
    for x in reduce(apply, [itertools.chain.from_iterable] * n, iterable):
        yield x
```

A function that recursively flattens all lists could look like this:

```
def flatten_lists(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        for b in a:
            for x in flatten_lists(b):
                yield x
    else:
        yield a
```

Comment: I understand this as I am not new to programming, only to python :) But what if it would be deeper? Are there any better ways to that? That work on any deepness

Comment: @maxpovver: It depends on what you want.  If you just flatten arbitrary iterables, you will also flatten out your tuples.  You could write a recursive function that flattens all lists, if this is what you want.  You could also write a generic function that takes the number of levels you want to flatten as an argument.  You can do all that, but you didn't ask for it. :)

Comment: If I get it right, your code won't help on this: [ [ [1,2,3], [1,2,3] ], [ [1,2,3], [1,2,3, [1, 2, 3] ] ].

Comment: @maxpovver: No, it doesn't, since this isn't what you asked for.

Comment: tried you code, it loses items order

Comment: @maxpovver: I don't think so.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: there was error in my tuples using @SvenMarnach

Comment: @maxpovver The third solution I gave is a more memory-efficient alternative to karthikr's answer.

Comment: that's why I accepted yours, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)]
    else:
        return [x]
```

This answer is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158522/1628832 but checking for the specific `list` type instead of an iterable.

For optimization, memory efficiency, etc.. you can use `yield` operation too.

Demo

```
>>> year = 2015
>>> x = calendar.Calendar.yeardays2calendar(calendar.Calendar(), year, 1)
>>> flatten(x)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 0), (13, 1), (14, 2), (15, 3), (16, 4), (17, 5), (18, 6), (19, 0), (20, 1), (21, 2), (22, 3), (23, 4), (24, 5), (25, 6), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2, the following one liner solution will currently work:

```
import compiler, itertools

lpairs = [[[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6)], [(5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 6)], [(12, 0), (13, 1)]]]]

print [(x,y) for x,y in itertools.izip(*[iter(compiler.ast.flatten(lpairs))]*2)]
```

Gives:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 0), (13, 1)]
```

Note, the Python `compiler` module has been deprecated.