# fmap and "flat map" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

All this time, when any Haskell lecture spoke of "flat map", usually in relation to Monads, I thought it was called "flat" for a reason, i.e. it flattens out the container. So

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

would be processed just as if it were

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

But now I discover that fmap and map are basically the same thing, the only difference being the application of one for functors and the other for just lists. And that was only done, in the end, to avoid confusing error messages when using map.

Is that true? And if so why did `f` in fmap come to mean "flat", why not "functor map"?

Comment: The `f` in `fmap` doesn't mean `flat`. The equivalent of `flatMap` in Haskell is `(>>=)`. The `map` function for lists was defined first so another name was needed for the more general `fmap` function.

Comment: Rather, `fmap` is the generalization of `map` to other functors besides the list functor. Whoever told you that `fmap` was short for `flat map` was mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure that the lecture you allude to was referring to `fmap` when saying "flat map"? It'd make more sense if it had been referring to `concatMap` (aka `>>=`), which is often called `flatMap` in other languages and behaves in the way you expected.

Comment: Sigh, I am so confused. I thought that's what they meant when they said "flat map". I've heard them talk about "flat map" being the basis of what a Monad is, and I thought they were talking about fmap. I never once heard that >>= was flatMap. Can any one show me an example of using `>>=` as a "flat map"?

Comment: @trans `[1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x,x]`

Comment: If they said it's the basis for monads, they were definitely talking about `>>=`, which is part of the Monad typeclass. `fmap` is the basis for functors.

Comment: `[[1],[2]] >>= map (+1)` ~> `[2,3]`

Comment: Okay that is starting to clear some thing up! But why do we need the `map` in the example `[[1],[2]] >>= map (+1)` if `>>=` is already flatMap?

Comment: @trans It's calling flatMap (`>>=`) on the outer list and `map` on each inner list. Like it's calling `map (+1) [1]` and `map (+1) [2]` and then flattening the results into one list.

Comment: Why does `[[1,2],[3,4]] >>= \x -> x` produces `[1,2,3,4]` but `[[1,2],[3,4]] >>= \x -> [x]` produces `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. Why isn't the later `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`?

Comment: @sepp2k if I take out the inner list, e.g. `[1,2,3,4] >>= (negate)` I don't get a result, just `:: Num [b] => [b]`, why is that? How to get a list?

Comment: @trans "Why isn't the later `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`" because `x` is the sublist, so if you were mapping instead of flat mapping `map (\x -> x) [[1,2], [3,4]]` would be [[1,2],[3,4]]. If you flatten that you get [1,2,3,4]. If you do `map (\x -> [x]) [[1,2], [3,4]]` you get `[[1,2]], [3,4]]`, i.e. you just add another layer of lists around each sublist. And if you flatten that (by one layer), you get `[[1,2], [3,4]]`. Another way to think of it is that you're inserting ++ between the functions results. So you get `[[1,2]] ++ [[3,4]]`, which is `[[1,2], [3,4]]`.

Comment: The flattening is performed last, not first. In `[[1,2],[3,4]] >>= \x -> [x]` we take every element of the list and bind it to `x` (hence `x=[1,2]` and `x=[3,4]`), then we apply the function `\x->[x]` to each `x`, obtaining the result list `[ [[1,2]], [[3,4]] ]`. Finally, we flatten the last list to the result: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`.

Comment: @trans `>>=` needs the function to produce a list (or generally a value of the same monad). `negate` produces a number, not a list. So Haskell tries to make this work by saying it only works with the types of numbers that are also lists, but since no such type exists (though you could define it), that's pretty useless.

Comment: Perhaps it helps thinking of `>>=` as `\x f -> join (fmap f x)`, where the `join` is the flattening -- for lists we have `join :: [[a]]->[a]`. Hence the name flatMap in some languages: use map/fmap, and then flatten/join.

Comment: This comment thread is getting a bit out of hand. Perhaps someone could summarize the main points in a community wiki answer?

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Yeah a summary would be good. This really clears things up for me. One important one that I bet most Haskellers(?) don't even think to mention is that the flattening is only *one* level deep. I had thought it was all levels. When it comers to Haskell there seems to be a huge difference between actually using the language and listening to lectures about it. :-)

Comment: This question has four close votes. At this stage, it seems unnecessary to close it just because it came out of a misunderstanding. I have just edited the title so that it doesn't state that misunderstanding, thus making things clearer for the posterity.

Comment: I still believe there is no point in closing this question. Reopen vote cast.

Answer (score 43):

> And if so, why did `f` in `fmap` come to mean “flat”, why not “functor map”?

Your intuition is right: the `f` in `fmap` **does** stand for “functor map”, not “flat map” at all. In fact, in newer, similar languages, such as PureScript, the name is just `map`. The Haskell `map` was defined first for lists, though, so coming up with a new name was difficult. Using the F from Functor was an easy, if not particularly creative, choice.

It is more likely that the lecturer was referring to the monadic bind function, `>>=`. Due to `x >>= f`’s equivalence to `join (fmap f x)`, bind is also sometimes called `flatMap` in other languages. It has the behavior you expect on lists, for example:

```
> [1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x,x]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

It’s important to keep in mind, though, that this “flat map” does not recursively flatten to an arbitrary depth. In fact, writing such a function isn’t really possible in Haskell without some complicated typeclass trickery. Try it yourself: what would the type signature for a `flatten` function look like, even one that operates directly on lists?

```
flatten :: ??? -> [a]
```

The `>>=` function is very simple in comparison: it is like `fmap`, but every output element must be wrapped in the functor, and `>>=` shallowly “flattens” the results into a single wrapper. This operation is the essence of what a monad is, which is why the `>>=` function lives in the `Monad` typeclass, but `fmap` is in `Functor`.

<sub>This answer is taken from some of the comments on the original question, so I have marked it community wiki. Edits and improvements are welcome.</sub>

Comment: It's not just numbers though, even a list when there are different depths, `[[[1,2]],[3],[4]] >>= \x -> x` only produces `:: (Num [t], Num t) => [[t]]`, not `[[1,2],3,4]`.

Comment: @trans Note that `[[[1,2]],[3],[4]]` is not a valid Haskell value. It does not have a type—it is neither `Num t => [[t]]` nor `Num t => [[[t]]]` because the depth is not consistent.

Comment: The reason you get that type is because of the way `Num` works, so it infers a type of `Num t => [[t]]` where it expects `[1, 2]` to have a `Num` instance. Of course, it does not. Try with non-numbers to get clearer results.

Comment: "Writing such a function isn't really possible in Haskell without some complicated typeclass trickery" - I disagree. `data Nested f a = Flat a | Nested (f (Nested f a)) deriving Foldable` is a pretty simple type for arbitrarily nested `Foldable`s

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I meant using only the built-in `[]` type. It’s obviously pretty easy if you use your own wrapper.

Comment: It is incorrect to assert that `map` was initially defined for lists in Haskell. [Haskell 1.3 had it right](/questions/18761302/why-were-haskell-98s-standard-classes-made-inferior-to-haskell-1-3s).

Comment: @Rhymoid Feel free to edit the answer (it’s community wiki for a reason).

Answer (score 14):

Here are some explicit equivalent examples of how to do `flatMap` in Haskell.

```
Prelude> map (replicate 3) [1..4]
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]
Prelude> fmap (replicate 3) [1..4]
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]
Prelude> concat [[1,2],[3,4]]
[1,2,3,4]
Prelude> concat (map (replicate 3) [1..4])
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
Prelude> concat $ map (replicate 3) [1..4]
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
Prelude> concatMap (replicate 3) [1..4]
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
Prelude> replicate 3 `concatMap` [1..4]
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
Prelude> [1..4] >>= replicate 3
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

It should be clear that `flatMap` is map first and then flat, you flatten the output of the map, as opposed to flattening the input list you are about to process (this isn't `flatMap`, this has no name, it is just a flat and then map).